# filtering file according to the lowest number in a column of each line

Tags: awk

I have the following file:

```
chr01_pilon3.g13.t1 trnscript:OIT01734  transcript:OIT01734 1.1e-107    389.8   1000    218 992 1   216 130 345 MDALTRHIQGDVPWCMLFADDIILIDETRAGVSERLEIWRQTLESKGFKISRSKTEYLECKFGDEPSGVGREVMLGSQAIAKRDSVRYLGSVIQGDGEIDGDVTHRIGAGWSKWRLASGVLCDKKIPHKLKGKFFRAMVRPAMFYEAECWPVKNSHIQRMKVAEMRMLRWMCGHTRLDKIKNEVIRQKVGVAPVDKKMGEARLRWFGHVRRRGPDA    MDALTRHIQGDVPWCMLFADDIVLIDETRVGVNERLEVWRQTLESKGFKLSRSKTEYLECKFSAESSEVGRDVKLGSQVIAKRDSFRYLGSVIQGEGEIDGDVTHRIGAGWSKWRLASGVLCDKKVPQKLKGKFYRAVVRPAMLYGAECWPVKNSHVQRMKVAEMRMLRWMRGLTRLDRIRNEVIREKVGVALVDEKMREARLRWYGHVRRRRPDA    MDALTRHIQGDVPWCMLFADDIILIDETRAGVSERLEIWRQTLESKGFKISRSKTEYLECKFGDEPSGVGREVMLGSQAIAKRDSVRYLGSVIQGDGEIDGDVTHRIGAGWSKWRLASGVLCDKKIPHKLKGKFFRAMVRPAMFYEAECWPVKNSHIQRMKVAEMRMLRWMCGHTRLDKIKNEVIRQKVGVAPVDKKMGEARLRWFGHVRRRGPDAR*  MKVWERVVEARVREMTSISVNQFGFMPGRSTTEAIHLVRRLVEHFRDKKKDLHMVFIDLENAYDKVPREVLWRCLEAKSVPEAYIRVIKDMYDGAKTRVRTVGGDSDHFPVVMGLHQGSALSPLLFALVMDALTRHIQGDVPWCMLFADDIVLIDETRVGVNERLEVWRQTLESKGFKLSRSKTEYLECKFSAESSEVGRDVKLGSQVIAKRDSFRYLGSVIQGEGEIDGDVTHRIGAGWSKWRLASGVLCDKKVPQKLKGKFYRAVVRPAMLYGAECWPVKNSHVQRMKVAEMRMLRWMRGLTRLDRIRNEVIREKVGVALVDEKMREARLRWYGHVRRRRPDAPVRIYKSAILGHLNSHGSQNALAGPVEAEENRQKTKKEVMEEIIQKSKFFKAQKAKDREENDELTEQLDKDFTSLVESKALLSLTQPDKINALKALVNKNISVGNVKKDEVADVPRKASIGKEKPDTYEMLVSEMALDMRARPSDRTKTPEEIAQEEKERLELLEQEXXXXXXXXXXXXXXDGNASDDNSKLVKDPRTVSGDDLGDDLEEVPRTKLGWIGEILRRKENELESEDAASSGDSDDGEDEGXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXDEEQGKTQTIKDWEQSDDDIIDTELEDDDEGFGDDAKKVVKIKDHKEENLSITVAAENKKKMQVFYGVLLQYFAVLANKKPLNSKLLNLLVKPLMEMSAVSPYFAAICARQRLQRTRAQFCEDLKNTGKSSWPSLKTIFLLRLWSMIFPCSDFRHCVMTPAILLMCEYLMRCTIISGRDIAIASFLCSLLLSVIKQSQKFCPEAIVFIQTLLMAALDRKQRSNSQLDNLMEIKELGPLLCIRSSKVEMDSLDFLTLMDLPEDSQYFHSDNYRTSMLVTVLETLQGFVNVYKELISFPEIFMLISKLLCKMAGENHIPDALREKIKDVSQLIDTKAQEHHMLRQPLKMRKKKPVPIRMLNPKFEENFVKGRDYDPDRERA    389.8   1000    216 85.6    185 31  200 0   0   92.6    0   22IV6AV2SN4IV11IL12GSDA1PS1GE3ED1MK4AV6VF9DE29IV1HQ6FY2MV5FL1EG10IV14CR1HL4KR1KR5QE5PL2KE2GR6FY6GR3 85.6    1.1e-107    99.1
gene.92134.0.0.p1   NisylASAF01033898g0006.1    NisylASAF01033898g0006.1    2.6e-302    1037.7  2682    571 548 2   570 4   548 SRDLRVAQLPLIFIGKLRQTGGESKLPSFTTVPMAFSRRXXXXXSRRRWLIPAISAAFGFLLIFIFFLSILAPSPNGNRLFHPRRRSLGDNDADTDEIEDSQSHVPARSGGVSDRDIWSSRNSKFFYGCSNASNEFLKAQDITHPNRYLSIVTSGGLNQQRTGITDAVVAARILNATLVVPKLDKSSYWKDSSGFSDIFDVDWFIKYLAKDVSIVKELPLRRGQIWSPYRMRVPRKCTDRCYINRVLPVLNKKHAVQITKFDYRLANKLDTDLQKLRCRVNYHALKFADPILGMGEKLVQRMRMRSSRFIALHLRFEPDMLAFSGCYYGGGDKERRELGKIRKKWKTLHDSDPDKARRHGRCPLTPEEVGLMLRSLGYGEDVHIYVASGEIYGGEETLTLLKALFPNFHTKDTLATKDELEPFSAFSSRMAALDFIVCDESDVFVTNNHGNMAKILAGRRRFFGHKPTIRPNGRKLYRLFLNRNYMTEKEFVYRVGKYQRGFMGEPKEVGPSWGVFHENPSSCICEKVDNATGQISHSTSRLETLSKVTSNDYDIDISENQELDMLLSD   SRDLRVAQLPLIFIGKLRQTGGESKLPSFTTVPMAFSRRXXXXXSRRRWLIPAISAAFGFLLIFIFFLSILAPSPNGNRLFHLPRRRSSGDNDADNEIEDSQSHVPAGSGGVSDRDIWSSRNSKFFYGCSNASNEFLKAQDITHPNRYLSIVTSGGLNQQRTGITDAVVAARILNATLVVPKLDKSSYWKDSSGFSDIFDVDWFIKYLAKDVSIVKELPLRRGQIWSPYRMRVPRKCTDRCYINRVLPVLNKKHAVQITKFDYRLANKLDTDLQKLRCRVNYHSLKFADPILRMGEKLVQRMRMRSSHFIALHLRFEPDMLAFSGCYYGGGDKERRELGKIRKKWKTLHDSDPDKARRHGRCPLTPEEVGLMLRSLGYGEDVHIYVASGEIYGGEETLTPLKALFPNFHTKDTLATKDELEPFSAFSSRMAALDFIVCDESDPTIRPNGRKLYRLFLNRNYMTEKEFVYRVGKYQRGFMGEPKEVGPSWGVFHENPSSCICEKVDNATVEISHSTSRLETSPKVTSNDYDTDISENPELDMLLSD   QSRDLRVAQLPLIFIGKLRQTGGESKLPSFTTVPMAFSRRXXXXXSRRRWLIPAISAAFGFLLIFIFFLSILAPSPNGNRLFHPRRRSLGDNDADTDEIEDSQSHVPARSGGVSDRDIWSSRNSKFFYGCSNASNEFLKAQDITHPNRYLSIVTSGGLNQQRTGITDAVVAARILNATLVVPKLDKSSYWKDSSGFSDIFDVDWFIKYLAKDVSIVKELPLRRGQIWSPYRMRVPRKCTDRCYINRVLPVLNKKHAVQITKFDYRLANKLDTDLQKLRCRVNYHALKFADPILGMGEKLVQRMRMRSSRFIALHLRFEPDMLAFSGCYYGGGDKERRELGKIRKKWKTLHDSDPDKARRHGRCPLTPEEVGLMLRSLGYGEDVHIYVASGEIYGGEETLTLLKALFPNFHTKDTLATKDELEPFSAFSSRMAALDFIVCDESDVFVTNNHGNMAKILAGRRRFFGHKPTIRPNGRKLYRLFLNRNYMTEKEFVYRVGKYQRGFMGEPKEVGPSWGVFHENPSSCICEKVDNATGQISHSTSRLETLSKVTSNDYDIDISENQELDMLLSD* MTLSRDLRVAQLPLIFIGKLRQTGGESKLPSFTTVPMAFSRRXXXXXSRRRWLIPAISAAFGFLLIFIFFLSILAPSPNGNRLFHLPRRRSSGDNDADNEIEDSQSHVPAGSGGVSDRDIWSSRNSKFFYGCSNASNEFLKAQDITHPNRYLSIVTSGGLNQQRTGITDAVVAARILNATLVVPKLDKSSYWKDSSGFSDIFDVDWFIKYLAKDVSIVKELPLRRGQIWSPYRMRVPRKCTDRCYINRVLPVLNKKHAVQITKFDYRLANKLDTDLQKLRCRVNYHSLKFADPILRMGEKLVQRMRMRSSHFIALHLRFEPDMLAFSGCYYGGGDKERRELGKIRKKWKTLHDSDPDKARRHGRCPLTPEEVGLMLRSLGYGEDVHIYVASGEIYGGEETLTPLKALFPNFHTKDTLATKDELEPFSAFSSRMAALDFIVCDESDPTIRPNGRKLYRLFLNRNYMTEKEFVYRVGKYQRGFMGEPKEVGPSWGVFHENPSSCICEKVDNATVEISHSTSRLETSPKVTSNDYDTDISENPELDMLLSD    1037.7  2682    570 93.2    531 13  533 3   26  93.5    0   82-L5LS6TND-11RG175AS8GR14RH91LP42V-F-V-T-N-N-H-G-N-M-A-K-I-L-A-G-R-R-R-F-F-G-H-K-66GVQE10LSSP8IT5QP8   93.2    2.6e-302    99.6
gene.96656.0.5.p2   NisylKD954897g0030.1    NisylKD954897g0030.1    7.7e-75 280.0   715 140 968 1   139 371 509 MRCKYLTLNTPMKKWELHGIAILLQSCPWVEMLHINTESAFEVYHFGLHYKNSNDFNGENYWISRPCWVLHLKTLRIHGYEWWDGDEYMLSFLQVVLKNGMVLQKIIIDFFEINSYEKLTKKLLSFPRSSREAVILFSS MRCKYLTLNTPMKKWELPGIAILLQSCPQVEMLHINTESAFEEYHFGSHFKNSNDFNGENYWISRPCWVLHLKTLRIHGYEWWDGDEYILSFLQVVLKNGMVLQKIIIDFFEINSYEKLTKKLLSFPRSSREAVILFSN MRCKYLTLNTPMKKWELHGIAILLQSCPWVEMLHINTESAFEVYHFGLHYKNSNDFNGENYWISRPCWVLHLKTLRIHGYEWWDGDEYMLSFLQVVLKNGMVLQKIIIDFFEINSYEKLTKKLLSFPRSSREAVILFSS*    MSESEGEHEENLDYDSPRYSPYSXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXSDQSYYGGKCHKTEKTDRISALPDSLILHILSSLDMGEVVRTGVLSKRWHLLWTSQQSLIFSYSGQHVNGIYKFVIFIDNTLLLCRSGMVKKFSVDFIYSKRFVRHVNRWMIFIKNKLVEELDLNLRSRGNLIEIYNLPQIMYFDVRLRHLSLCNCNLVPKEEIYWPALRDLEIGYAELNRDVIKKICSGCRALESLKFRSCYGVDYFDIDSKSVKKLVIHEYGRQNHDDADDDDDELGIYARNVTSLEICGYFHKRILVLEDVKALLDAKLDFYRNTDDYEIEREFRTDQNMLKNLLVSLQHVEKLSIGTWCLQVLTSLEIRNLPCPRMRCKYLTLNTPMKKWELPGIAILLQSCPQVEMLHINTESAFEEYHFGSHFKNSNDFNGENYWISRPCWVLHLKTLRIHGYEWWDGDEYILSFLQVVLKNGMVLQKIIIDFFEINSYEKLTKKLLSFPRSSREAVILFSNRFSSLPDSVLLHILSFLPFDDVVRTTLLCKQWRPLWSFSTSLNFIHRPKDFISLKKFASFVDKSLINLHCNNSSISKLHLDFPFKRCFSSDVTVWVLFAITHKVKELNLILSSDAEDLYKLPKRLFSNPFIEKVNWVGCKFDKVEVFRWDSLRELRIGSIEFCDDMVRKVVFGSPCLELLELDNCWGFKRLDLVGGKVSKLVVNGYNGEAVKKNSMLLDFEVVEIEAPCVKVLELKGCFRRMNNIQLKNVMSCVSVKLDFQFTKDEERVNYVDMLMGMIGSLRHVKDVMLGTWCIEVMSSWPMNILPFSMSSYECLTLHTPIQERYLPGIVRILQSSSNLRTLIIHMAPPYFEFEACFIPIVYDVYSVGGRCQLSMLSKNCGLHLKKIRICCFEGMRSGQEVLFLRDLLLVCANLEEMVIEWRSGHQNSSIRDASDEFVAESLLMVQKRSRNAVILFNN    280.0   715 139 95.0    132 7   135 0   0   97.1    0   17HP10WQ13VE4LS1YF38MI49SN  95.0    7.7e-75 99.3
gene.90968.0.2.p2   transcript:OIT02339 transcript:OIT02339 1.3e-209    729.2   1881    391 1270    1   388 881 1268    MNEEASQVANDAIGSIRTVASFCAEEKVMEMYQKKSEAPLKRGVKKGLVSGVGLGFSNFVLFCLYALAFYLGAVLVRHDKAKFSEVFKVFFALTMASIGLSFLSNLPSDLSKGKGAAASIFEILDSKPRIDSSSNEGITLDAIEGNIELQHISFRYPTRPDMQIFRDLSLSIPAGKTVALVGESGSGKSTVISLLERFYDPEQGNIYLDGVEIRKFNLRWLRQQMGLVGQEPILFNETISSNIAYGREGEVTEEEIISVAKSSNAHNFISSLPNGYKTTVGERGVHLSGGQKQRIAIARAILKDPKILLLDEATSALDTESERIVQEALDRVMVNRTTVVVAHRLTTVKNADVIAVVKNGVVAEKGTHDMLMNNPQGVYASLVALQTG    MNEEASQVANDAIGSIRTVASFCAEEKVMEMYQKKSEAPLKRGVKNGLVSGVGLGFSNFVLFCLYALAFYLGAVLVKHDKAKFSEVFKVFFALTMASIGLSVLSNLPSDLSKGKGAAASIIEILDSKPRIDSSSNEGITLDAIEGNIELQHISFRYPTRPDMQIFRDLSLSIPAGKTVALVGESGSGKSTVISLLERFYDPEQGNIYLDGVEIRKFNLRWLRQQMGLVGQEPILFNETISSNIAYGREGEVTEEEIISVAKSSNAHNFISSLPNGYKTTVGERGVQLSGGQKQRIAIARAILKDPKILLLDEATSALDTESERIVQEALDRVMVNRTTVVVAHRLTTVKNADVIAVVKNGVVAEKGTHDMLMNNPQGVYASLVALQTG    MNEEASQVANDAIGSIRTVASFCAEEKVMEMYQKKSEAPLKRGVKKGLVSGVGLGFSNFVLFCLYALAFYLGAVLVRHDKAKFSEVFKVFFALTMASIGLSFLSNLPSDLSKGKGAAASIFEILDSKPRIDSSSNEGITLDAIEGNIELQHISFRYPTRPDMQIFRDLSLSIPAGKTVALVGESGSGKSTVISLLERFYDPEQGNIYLDGVEIRKFNLRWLRQQMGLVGQEPILFNETISSNIAYGREGEVTEEEIISVAKSSNAHNFISSLPNGYKTTVGERGVHLSGGQKQRIAIARAILKDPKILLLDEATSALDTESERIVQEALDRVMVNRTTVVVAHRLTTVKNADVIAVVKNGVVAEKGTHDMLMNNPQGVYASLVALQTGAT* MAEGGEPSSARRKEEDDQKVPFYMLFAFADRTDVILMLFGTLGAIASGISKPLMSLIFGDLVNSYGKSNQSNILDQVSGISLKFVYLAIGSGIASVFQIACWVVTGERQATRIKCLYLKTILRQDIGFFDTQSATGEFIERMSGDTILVQEAMGDKVANFIMNISTFIGGFVVAFIKGWLLTLVLLTSIPATAISFGCVALVLSKMSGSGQVAYADAGKVVEQTVGGIRTVASFTGEKLAIEDYNSKLESAYSATIKQALASGLGLGTILTLIFFSYGLAIWYGAKLIIEKDYKGGDIISVIFAVMLGGSSLGQASPSLNAFSAGQAAAYKIFETIKRTPKIDPYDPSGIELEDIKGEIELKDVYFKYPARPDVQIFSGFSLYIPSGKTAALVGQSGSGKSTVISLLERFYDPEAGEILIDGVEIKKFQLKWLRQQMGLVSQEPVLFATTIRENIIYGKENASEEEIRNAIQLANAAKFIDKLPKGLDTMVGGHGTQISGGQKQRIAIARAILKDPRILLLDEATSALDVESERIVQDALSNIMVNRTTVVVAHRLTTIRNADLIAVVHLGKLVEQGTHDELIKDPEGAYSQLVQMQQKTKHVENTKGKEIEELNAPKRLSYSKNVSGRSRRFSLSGRKSASKGSSSKFSFAYDLGVSGVVDFHESIRREDGAGTSEYIADTKKKVSTQKLMSLAYLNKPELPIMLVGTVAAAINGMVFPVFGLLVSTIIKIFYESHHELRKDSRFWALMFVVIGIVVMIVSPLQNYAFGVAGAKLIQRIRSMTFSKLVYQEISWFDDPANSCGAIGARLSSDASTIRNMVGDALATLVQNISTIVTGLVIALIANWILALITIAIMPLLALQGYIQIKLLQESNNEAKLMNEEASQVANDAIGSIRTVASFCAEEKVMEMYQKKSEAPLKRGVKNGLVSGVGLGFSNFVLFCLYALAFYLGAVLVKHDKAKFSEVFKVFFALTMASIGLSVLSNLPSDLSKGKGAAASIIEILDSKPRIDSSSNEGITLDAIEGNIELQHISFRYPTRPDMQIFRDLSLSIPAGKTVALVGESGSGKSTVISLLERFYDPEQGNIYLDGVEIRKFNLRWLRQQMGLVGQEPILFNETISSNIAYGREGEVTEEEIISVAKSSNAHNFISSLPNGYKTTVGERGVQLSGGQKQRIAIARAILKDPKILLLDEATSALDTESERIVQEALDRVMVNRTTVVVAHRLTTVKNADVIAVVKNGVVAEKGTHDMLMNNPQGVYASLVALQTGTA  729.2   1881    388 98.7    383 5   384 0   0   99.0    0   45KN30RK24FV18FI164HQ102    98.7    1.3e-209    99.2
gene.69001.1.0.p1   NisylKD955766g0010.1    NisylKD955766g0010.1    1.8e-206    718.8   1854    393 530 1   384 1   384 MKEMCLAVAPLPFRLGNNLIFHNPLSIGSSSHMDVTRLNSMGGTTTSLYAESAEKDLSDTVSSSRSEGVPLLHMISENESNNWISGDAVVRESEDDEILSLDGDQMSCSLSVVSDSSSLCGDDFIGFEVASEIFGQNFVDAEKSICSVELIAKPGDLVESGVEDDNVSKPFAVKIEEQITDGSSSKSSQVVVQLPLNKGLSAAVSRSVFEVDYIPLWGFTSVCGRRPEMEDALATVPRFLRIPLQMLVGHRVPDGVSRCLSHLTAHFFGVYDGHGGSQVANYCRDRVHAVLAEELEKFMANLNDESIRQNCQEQWKKAFTNCFLMVDDEVGGTGNHEAVAAETVGSTAVVAIVCSSHIIVANCGDSRAVLCRGKEPTALSVDHK    MKEMCLAVAPLPFRLGNNLIFRNPPSIGSSSHMDATRLNSMGDTTTSLYAESAEKDLSDTVSSSRSEGVPLLPMISENDRNNWIAGDAVVRESEDDEILSLDGDQVSCSLSVVSDSSSLCGDDFIGFEVASDIYGQNFVDAEKSICSVELIAKPGDLVESGVEDDNVSKPFAVKLEEQITDGSSSKSSQVVVQLPLNKGLSAAVSRSVFEVDYIPLWGFTSVCGRRPEMEDALATVPRFLRIPLQMLVGDRVPDGVSRCLSHLTAHFFGVYDGHGGSQVANYCRDRVHAVLAEELEKFMANLNDESIRQNCQDQWKKAFTNCFLKVDDEVGGTGNREAVAAETVGSTAVVAIVCSSHIIVANCGDSRAVLCRGKEPMALSVDHK    MKEMCLAVAPLPFRLGNNLIFHNPLSIGSSSHMDVTRLNSMGGTTTSLYAESAEKDLSDTVSSSRSEGVPLLHMISENESNNWISGDAVVRESEDDEILSLDGDQMSCSLSVVSDSSSLCGDDFIGFEVASEIFGQNFVDAEKSICSVELIAKPGDLVESGVEDDNVSKPFAVKIEEQITDGSSSKSSQVVVQLPLNKGLSAAVSRSVFEVDYIPLWGFTSVCGRRPEMEDALATVPRFLRIPLQMLVGHRVPDGVSRCLSHLTAHFFGVYDGHGGSQVANYCRDRVHAVLAEELEKFMANLNDESIRQNCQEQWKKAFTNCFLMVDDEVGGTGNHEAVAAETVGSTAVVAIVCSSHIIVANCGDSRAVLCRGKEPTALSVDHKVSETVVLV*   MKEMCLAVAPLPFRLGNNLIFRNPPSIGSSSHMDATRLNSMGDTTTSLYAESAEKDLSDTVSSSRSEGVPLLPMISENDRNNWIAGDAVVRESEDDEILSLDGDQVSCSLSVVSDSSSLCGDDFIGFEVASDIYGQNFVDAEKSICSVELIAKPGDLVESGVEDDNVSKPFAVKLEEQITDGSSSKSSQVVVQLPLNKGLSAAVSRSVFEVDYIPLWGFTSVCGRRPEMEDALATVPRFLRIPLQMLVGDRVPDGVSRCLSHLTAHFFGVYDGHGGSQVANYCRDRVHAVLAEELEKFMANLNDESIRQNCQDQWKKAFTNCFLKVDDEVGGTGNREAVAAETVGSTAVVAIVCSSHIIVANCGDSRAVLCRGKEPMALSVDHKPNREDEYARIEAAGGKVIQWNGHRVFGVLAMSRSIGDRYLKPWIIPDPEVMFIPRTKDDECLILASDGLWDVMSNEEACELARKRILLWHKKNGVTLTLERGQGIDPAAQAAAECLSNRATQKGSKDNITVIVVDLKAQRKFKSKT  718.8   1854    384 95.6    367 17  374 0   0   97.4    0   21HR2LP9VA7GD29HP5EDSR4SA20MV25ED1FY40IL74HD62ED11MK10HR40TM7   95.6    1.8e-206    97.7
gene.35466.0.0.p2   NiotoAWOL01S0001629g0004.1  NiotoAWOL01S0001629g0004.1  1.0e-59 229.6   584 118 889 1   118 669 786 QKPGSDDVFMEEEVLPKPSDEEMKTEDGGWTEVKETDEEEPSVKEEEMEVTPDATIHEVPVGKGLSGALKLLQERGTLKEDIEWGGRNMDKKKSKLVGIRGEDGKKEIRIERTDEYGR  QKPGSDDVFMEEEVLPKPSDEEMKTEDGGWTEVKETEEEEPSVKEEEMEVTPDATIHEVPVGKGLSGALKLLQERGTLKEDIEWGGRNMDKKKSKLVGIRGEDGKKEIRIERTDEYGR  QKPGSDDVFMEEEVLPKPSDEEMKTEDGGWTEVKETDEEEPSVKEEEMEVTPDATIHEVPVGKGLSGALKLLQERGTLKEDIEWGGRNMDKKKSKLVGIRGEDGKKEIRIERTDEYGR  MEIDGRERSVEMRDHDDSPVKERWEDGHYDLEESGHDKSKXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXDLXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXGRDAVDKEKGXXXXXXXXXXADEXXXXXXXXXXGNRRXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXAKQEIVSYEDDDRARNNAVETAGSQSSASKLEERILKMKEERLKKKSEGASEVMAWVSKSRKIEEKRTAEKERALQLSKIFEEQDKINDEESDDEEKARLAAKELGGMKVLHGLDKVVEGGAVVLTLKDQSILAGDDINQEVDVLENVEIGEQKKRDDAYKAAKKKTGIYDDKFNDDPGFERKILPQYDDPAEEEGVTLDATGGFSVDAEKKLEELRKRIQGSSSKTLAEDLNSSGKLLSDYYTQEEMLQFKKPKKKKSLRKKEKMDLDALEVEAKSSGLGVGDLGSRNDKTRQALREEMERAEAETKSKSYQAAYAKAEEASKALRPEKTNXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXELRKSLERARKLALQKQEGLAKTFPESIASLAISRANDSTVDNPSSVSGESQENKVVFTEMEEFVWGLQLDEEEQKPGSDDVFMEEEVLPKPSDEEMKTEDGGWTEVKETEEEEPSVKEEEMEVTPDATIHEVPVGKGLSGALKLLQERGTLKEDIEWGGRNMDKKKSKLVGIRGEDGKKEIRIERTDEYGRILTPKEAFRLLSHKFHGKGPGKMKQEKRMRQYQEELKIKQMKNSDTPSLSVERMREAQAQFKTPYLVLSGNVKPGQTSDPRSGFATVEKSLPGGLTPMLGDKK   229.6   584 118 99.2    117 1   118 0   0   100.0   0   36DE81  99.2    1.0e-59 100.0
gene.86248.0.0.p1   Nitab4.5_0000420g0110.1 Nitab4.5_0000420g0110.1 Protein of unknown function DUF538  8.2e-74 276.9   707 175 140 35  174 1   140 MTSQVTENHRENAEVFTNPAICKQKSLELLEQTNMPKGLLPLDDLIEVGRNHQTGFVWLKQKKAKEHRFKKIGKLVWYDTEVTAFVEDRRMKKLTGVKSKEILIWVTISDISIQDPEFQKITFATPTGISKAFPVSAFEE    MSSQVSENHRENAEVFTDPAICKQKSLELLEQINMPKGLLPLDDLIEVGRNHQTGFVWLKQKKAKEHRFKKIGKLVWYDTEVTAFIEDRRMKKLTGVKSKEILIWVTISDISIQDPEFQKITFATPTGISKAFPVSAFEE    THFLYFPFPLSHTEPQTKRNLNPISFPFSFAFTKMTSQVTENHRENAEVFTNPAICKQKSLELLEQTNMPKGLLPLDDLIEVGRNHQTGFVWLKQKKAKEHRFKKIGKLVWYDTEVTAFVEDRRMKKLTGVKSKEILIWVTISDISIQDPEFQKITFATPTGISKAFPVSAFEE* MSSQVSENHRENAEVFTDPAICKQKSLELLEQINMPKGLLPLDDLIEVGRNHQTGFVWLKQKKAKEHRFKKIGKLVWYDTEVTAFIEDRRMKKLTGVKSKEILIWVTISDISIQDPEFQKITFATPTGISKAFPVSAFEE    276.9   707 140 96.4    135 5   139 0   0   99.3    0   1TS3TS11ND14TI52VI54    96.4    8.2e-74 80.0
gene.9403.0.4.p1    transcript:OIT35479 transcript:OIT35479 8.5e-191    667.5   1721    690 406 1   378 1   378 MLSAPRVSPPAVAVAAPARFKFPNVCVNPVNLLLLHRNVGSSCKRVVVSTKAAYSRMPMDTPGAYQLIDKESGDKFIIWGGTEDDDSSIPSKEVLSWKPLASTPXXXXXXXXXXXXXDEASTRGLTGNFGRLKFRRMRDLVRKSYTKNKERDVIDHNKHNIADASSRSSFSSYNEPDQLKEQQTLSLPRGRAKIQQLDDKKNFQKLIRVEDEDRGIAIENVSKHFAGYSIDSHAQSARVVHPGSKASASPLRGWGGGSSHYSLKRDEIFRERQNLGDENNFFSRKSFQELGCSDYMIESLRNQHFVRPSHIQAMTFGPIIAGKSCIISDQSGSGKTLAYLLPLIQRLRQEELQGLSKPSSQSPRVVVLAPTAELASQV  MLSAPRAPPPAVAVAAPARFKFQNVCGNPVNLLLLHRNVGSSCKRVVVSTKAAYSRMPMDTPGAYQLIDKESGDKFIVWGGTEDDDSSIPSKEVLSWKPLASTSPDNNHPPPTQSSSNEASTRGLTGNFGRLKFRRMRDLVRKSYTKNKERDVIDHDKHNTTDASSRSSFSSYNEPGQLKEQQTLSLPRGRAKIQQLEDRKNSQKLIRVEDEDRDIAIENVSKHFAGYSSDSHAHSARVVHPGSKASASPLRGWGGGSSHYSLKREEIFRQRRNLDDENNFFSRKSFQELGCSDYMIESLRNQHFVRPSHIQAMTFGPIIAGKSCIISDQSGSGKTLAYLLPLIQRLRQEELQGLSKPSSQSPRVVVLAPTAELASQV  MLSAPRVSPPAVAVAAPARFKFPNVCVNPVNLLLLHRNVGSSCKRVVVSTKAAYSRMPMDTPGAYQLIDKESGDKFIIWGGTEDDDSSIPSKEVLSWKPLASTPXXXXXXXXXXXXXDEASTRGLTGNFGRLKFRRMRDLVRKSYTKNKERDVIDHNKHNIADASSRSSFSSYNEPDQLKEQQTLSLPRGRAKIQQLDDKKNFQKLIRVEDEDRGIAIENVSKHFAGYSIDSHAQSARVVHPGSKASASPLRGWGGGSSHYSLKRDEIFRERQNLGDENNFFSRKSFQELGCSDYMIESLRNQHFVRPSHIQAMTFGPIIAGKSCIISDQSGSGKTLAYLLPLIQRLRQEELQGLSKPSSQSPRVVVLAPTAELASQVLSTCRSFSKSGVPFHSMVVTGGFCQRTQLENLRQELDILIATPGRFMFLIKEGYLQLTNLKCAVLDEVDILFSDEDFETAFQCLINSSPITTQYLFVTATLPMDIYNKLVESFPDCELVSGPGMHRTSPGLEEFLVDCSGDETAEKSPDTAFINKKNALLHLVEDSPVPKTIVFCNKIDSCRKVENALKRFDRKGFSIKILPFHAALDQRRRLANMEEFRRSKMENVSLFLVCTDRASRGIDFEGVDHVVLFDYPRDPSEYVRRVGRTARGAGGKGKAFIFAVGKQVSLARRIMERNKKGHPVHDVPSILT*  MLSAPRAPPPAVAVAAPARFKFQNVCGNPVNLLLLHRNVGSSCKRVVVSTKAAYSRMPMDTPGAYQLIDKESGDKFIVWGGTEDDDSSIPSKEVLSWKPLASTSPDNNHPPPTQSSSNEASTRGLTGNFGRLKFRRMRDLVRKSYTKNKERDVIDHDKHNTTDASSRSSFSSYNEPGQLKEQQTLSLPRGRAKIQQLEDRKNSQKLIRVEDEDRDIAIENVSKHFAGYSSDSHAHSARVVHPGSKASASPLRGWGGGSSHYSLKREEIFRQRRNLDDENNFFSRKSFQELGCSDYMIESLRNQHFVRPSHIQAMTFGPIIAGKSCIISDQSGSGKTLAYLLPLIQRLRQEELQGLSKPSSQSPRVVVLAPTAELASQVCQISSSIKGTFATYSPYCSATTHTKRKK  667.5   1721    378 91.0    344 34  352 0   0   93.1    0   6VASP14PQ3VG50IV25PSXPXDXNXNXHXPXPXPXTXQXSXSXSDN38ND3ITAT14DG20DE1KR2FS11GD14IS4QH30DE4EQ1QR2GD102  91.0    8.5e-191    54.8
gene.69001.1.0.p2   NisylKD955766g0010.1    NisylKD955766g0010.1    1.8e-61 235.3   599 117 530 1   116 415 530 MSRSIGDRYLKPWIIPDPEVMFIPRTKDDECLILASDGLWDVMSNEEACELARKRILLWHKKNGVTLTLERGQGIDPAAQAAAECLSNRAIQKGSKDNITVIVVDLKAQRKFKSKT    MSRSIGDRYLKPWIIPDPEVMFIPRTKDDECLILASDGLWDVMSNEEACELARKRILLWHKKNGVTLTLERGQGIDPAAQAAAECLSNRATQKGSKDNITVIVVDLKAQRKFKSKT    MSRSIGDRYLKPWIIPDPEVMFIPRTKDDECLILASDGLWDVMSNEEACELARKRILLWHKKNGVTLTLERGQGIDPAAQAAAECLSNRAIQKGSKDNITVIVVDLKAQRKFKSKT*   MKEMCLAVAPLPFRLGNNLIFRNPPSIGSSSHMDATRLNSMGDTTTSLYAESAEKDLSDTVSSSRSEGVPLLPMISENDRNNWIAGDAVVRESEDDEILSLDGDQVSCSLSVVSDSSSLCGDDFIGFEVASDIYGQNFVDAEKSICSVELIAKPGDLVESGVEDDNVSKPFAVKLEEQITDGSSSKSSQVVVQLPLNKGLSAAVSRSVFEVDYIPLWGFTSVCGRRPEMEDALATVPRFLRIPLQMLVGDRVPDGVSRCLSHLTAHFFGVYDGHGGSQVANYCRDRVHAVLAEELEKFMANLNDESIRQNCQDQWKKAFTNCFLKVDDEVGGTGNREAVAAETVGSTAVVAIVCSSHIIVANCGDSRAVLCRGKEPMALSVDHKPNREDEYARIEAAGGKVIQWNGHRVFGVLAMSRSIGDRYLKPWIIPDPEVMFIPRTKDDECLILASDGLWDVMSNEEACELARKRILLWHKKNGVTLTLERGQGIDPAAQAAAECLSNRATQKGSKDNITVIVVDLKAQRKFKSKT  235.3   599 116 99.1    115 1   115 0   0   99.1    0   90IT25  99.1    1.8e-61 99.1
gene.91393.0.0.p1   Solyc12g056340.2.1  Solyc12g056340.2.1 RNA helicase DEAD38  1.8e-223    775.4   2001    437 806 24  437 393 806 LPAIETVLKASNSKSAQRVPPIDVLILCPTRELASQIAAEANVLLKYHESIGVQTLVGGTRFKEDQKRLESNPCQIIVATPGRLLDHIENKSGFSTRLMGLKMLILDEADHLLDLGFRKDIEKLVDCLPRKRQSLLFSATVPKEVRRVSQLVLKREHGYVDTVGLGLETNPKVKQFYLVAPHEQHFQLVHHLLTSHISEVPDYKVIVFCTTAMMTSLMFSLLREMKMNVREIHSRKPQLYRTRISDEFKETKRVILITSDVSARGMNYPDVTLVIQIGIPVDREQYIHRLGRTGREGKEGEGILLLAPWEQYFLDDIKDLPMENWPVPHLDPRAKVKIEEAIGKMDASVKEAAYHAWLGYYNSVREIGRDKTTLVELANQFSESIGLQKPPSLFRRTALKMGLKDIPGIRIRK*  LPAIETVLKASRKKSAQRVPPIDVLILCPTRELASQIAAEANVLLKYHEGIGVQTLVGGTRFKEDQKRLECDPCQIIVATPGRLLDHIENKSGFSTRIMGLKMLILDEADHLLDLGFRKDIEKLVDCLPRRRQSLLFSATVPKEVRRISQLVLKREYDYVDTVGLGLETNPKVKQFYLVAPHEQHFQVVHHLLSSHISEVPDYKVIVFCTTAMMTSLMFSLFHEMKMNVREIHSRKPQLYRTRISDEFKETKRVILITSDVSARGMNYPDVTLVIQVGLPVDREQYIHRLGRTGREGKEGEGILLLAPWEQYFLDDIKDLPMENWPVPRLDPRVKVKMEEAMEKMDTSVKESAYHAWLGYYNSVREVGRDKTTLVELANQFSESIGLDKPPSLFRRTALKMGLKDIPGIRIRK*  MLFPADYLHVSPVLFIAAIKVQQLPAIETVLKASNSKSAQRVPPIDVLILCPTRELASQIAAEANVLLKYHESIGVQTLVGGTRFKEDQKRLESNPCQIIVATPGRLLDHIENKSGFSTRLMGLKMLILDEADHLLDLGFRKDIEKLVDCLPRKRQSLLFSATVPKEVRRVSQLVLKREHGYVDTVGLGLETNPKVKQFYLVAPHEQHFQLVHHLLTSHISEVPDYKVIVFCTTAMMTSLMFSLLREMKMNVREIHSRKPQLYRTRISDEFKETKRVILITSDVSARGMNYPDVTLVIQIGIPVDREQYIHRLGRTGREGKEGEGILLLAPWEQYFLDDIKDLPMENWPVPHLDPRAKVKIEEAIGKMDASVKEAAYHAWLGYYNSVREIGRDKTTLVELANQFSESIGLQKPPSLFRRTALKMGLKDIPGIRIRK*   MGGGPRTFPGGLNKWQWKRLHEKKARDKENRLLDQEKQLYQARIRSQIRAKLTSSGEQSDFSNEQQPNYSPVSPQDHIRGLADRFMKEGAEDLWNEDDGPVNTPQINQQSGGISESIDLRKLRDTKFNDVPRSYSFQKARNFCTNISDVFAENCRTRNPTFSDSWSRQNKFLMFGWRLVNIENRNVNNLNGFLNYRCYSVDRMNGNKLRKLDFTRNESSQSEDKLRSVGLVVKGERKAKWPRFRPKPEESXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXRSRGSVKMMSSAALGKYDMKTKKRVPLKFVEDEDDLSLHVAAIRKEVKGRSMQKIETEEDEKETILSSKRFDEYDVSPLTVKALTAAGYVQMTKVQEATLSTCLEGKDALVKARTGTGKSAAFLLPAIETVLKASRKKSAQRVPPIDVLILCPTRELASQIAAEANVLLKYHEGIGVQTLVGGTRFKEDQKRLECDPCQIIVATPGRLLDHIENKSGFSTRIMGLKMLILDEADHLLDLGFRKDIEKLVDCLPRRRQSLLFSATVPKEVRRISQLVLKREYDYVDTVGLGLETNPKVKQFYLVAPHEQHFQVVHHLLSSHISEVPDYKVIVFCTTAMMTSLMFSLFHEMKMNVREIHSRKPQLYRTRISDEFKETKRVILITSDVSARGMNYPDVTLVIQVGLPVDREQYIHRLGRTGREGKEGEGILLLAPWEQYFLDDIKDLPMENWPVPRLDPRVKVKMEEAMEKMDTSVKESAYHAWLGYYNSVREVGRDKTTLVELANQFSESIGLDKPPSLFRRTALKMGLKDIPGIRIRK*  775.4   2001    414 94.0    389 25  402 0   0   97.1    0   11NRSK36SG20SCND25LI32KR16VI8HYGD29LV5TS27LFRH53IV1IL49HR4AV3IM3IMGE3AT4AS14IV20QD26    94.0    1.8e-223    94.7
gene.69001.1.3.p1   NisylKD955766g0010.1    NisylKD955766g0010.1    1.4e-228    792.3   2045    434 530 1   420 1   420 MKEMCLAVAPLPFRLGNNLIFHNPLSIGSSSHMDVTRLNSMGGTTTSLYAESAEKDLSDTVSSSRSEGVPLLHMISENESNNWISGDAVVRESEDDEILSLDGDQMSCSLSVVSDSSSLCGDDFIGFEVASEIFGQNFVDAEKSICSVELIAKPGDLVESGVEDDNVSKPFAVKIEEQITDGSSSKSSQVVVQLPLNKGLSAAVSRSVFEVDYIPLWGFTSVCGRRPEMEDALATVPRFLRIPLQMLVGHRVPDGVSRCLSHLTAHFFGVYDGHGGSQVANYCRDRVHAVLAEELEKFMANLNDESIRQNCQEQWKKAFTNCFLMVDDEVGGTGNHEAVAAETVGSTAVVAIVCSSHIIVANCGDSRAVLCRGKEPTALSVDHKPNREDEYARIEAAGGKVIQWNGHRVFGVLAMSRSIG    MKEMCLAVAPLPFRLGNNLIFRNPPSIGSSSHMDATRLNSMGDTTTSLYAESAEKDLSDTVSSSRSEGVPLLPMISENDRNNWIAGDAVVRESEDDEILSLDGDQVSCSLSVVSDSSSLCGDDFIGFEVASDIYGQNFVDAEKSICSVELIAKPGDLVESGVEDDNVSKPFAVKLEEQITDGSSSKSSQVVVQLPLNKGLSAAVSRSVFEVDYIPLWGFTSVCGRRPEMEDALATVPRFLRIPLQMLVGDRVPDGVSRCLSHLTAHFFGVYDGHGGSQVANYCRDRVHAVLAEELEKFMANLNDESIRQNCQDQWKKAFTNCFLKVDDEVGGTGNREAVAAETVGSTAVVAIVCSSHIIVANCGDSRAVLCRGKEPMALSVDHKPNREDEYARIEAAGGKVIQWNGHRVFGVLAMSRSIG    MKEMCLAVAPLPFRLGNNLIFHNPLSIGSSSHMDVTRLNSMGGTTTSLYAESAEKDLSDTVSSSRSEGVPLLHMISENESNNWISGDAVVRESEDDEILSLDGDQMSCSLSVVSDSSSLCGDDFIGFEVASEIFGQNFVDAEKSICSVELIAKPGDLVESGVEDDNVSKPFAVKIEEQITDGSSSKSSQVVVQLPLNKGLSAAVSRSVFEVDYIPLWGFTSVCGRRPEMEDALATVPRFLRIPLQMLVGHRVPDGVSRCLSHLTAHFFGVYDGHGGSQVANYCRDRVHAVLAEELEKFMANLNDESIRQNCQEQWKKAFTNCFLMVDDEVGGTGNHEAVAAETVGSTAVVAIVCSSHIIVANCGDSRAVLCRGKEPTALSVDHKPNREDEYARIEAAGGKVIQWNGHRVFGVLAMSRSIGMFLLPTLLSSICK*  MKEMCLAVAPLPFRLGNNLIFRNPPSIGSSSHMDATRLNSMGDTTTSLYAESAEKDLSDTVSSSRSEGVPLLPMISENDRNNWIAGDAVVRESEDDEILSLDGDQVSCSLSVVSDSSSLCGDDFIGFEVASDIYGQNFVDAEKSICSVELIAKPGDLVESGVEDDNVSKPFAVKLEEQITDGSSSKSSQVVVQLPLNKGLSAAVSRSVFEVDYIPLWGFTSVCGRRPEMEDALATVPRFLRIPLQMLVGDRVPDGVSRCLSHLTAHFFGVYDGHGGSQVANYCRDRVHAVLAEELEKFMANLNDESIRQNCQDQWKKAFTNCFLKVDDEVGGTGNREAVAAETVGSTAVVAIVCSSHIIVANCGDSRAVLCRGKEPMALSVDHKPNREDEYARIEAAGGKVIQWNGHRVFGVLAMSRSIGDRYLKPWIIPDPEVMFIPRTKDDECLILASDGLWDVMSNEEACELARKRILLWHKKNGVTLTLERGQGIDPAAQAAAECLSNRATQKGSKDNITVIVVDLKAQRKFKSKT  792.3   2045    420 96.0    403 17  410 0   0   97.6    0   21HR2LP9VA7GD29HP5EDSR4SA20MV25ED1FY40IL74HD62ED11MK10HR40TM43  96.0    1.4e-228    96.8
gene.18823.1.1.p2   transcript:OIT25066 transcript:OIT25066 1.0e-56 219.5   558 115 185 1   113 72  184 MLGQMVGRIRAKPGGKLEMGEASMVEKYDRALPKLRNTTSESSRYEERPAPPGTLNVAQIREIILLHQGRADDHKGSMDINQIAQRFRVDAAQVQRILQFVSLPPEDTSKKRS   MLGQMVGRIQAKPGGKLEMGEASVVEKYDRALPKLRNTTSESSRYEERPAPPGTLNVAQIREIILLHQGRADDHKGSMDINQIAQRFRVDAAQIQRILQFVSLPPEDTSKKRS   MLGQMVGRIRAKPGGKLEMGEASMVEKYDRALPKLRNTTSESSRYEERPAPPGTLNVAQIREIILLHQGRADDHKGSMDINQIAQRFRVDAAQVQRILQFVSLPPEDTSKKRSI* MGQAFRRATGRIGSSNVDAASSQLKKPIDRTPPPVPAAIKTPSDNVAPVAGSSPKDAVGETLEERDPKFDAMLGQMVGRIQAKPGGKLEMGEASVVEKYDRALPKLRNTTSESSRYEERPAPPGTLNVAQIREIILLHQGRADDHKGSMDINQIAQRFRVDAAQIQRILQFVSLPPEDTSKKRST   219.5   558 113 97.3    110 3   113 0   0   100.0   0   9RQ13MV69VI19   97.3    1.0e-56 98.3
gene.69001.1.2.p1   NisylKD955766g0010.1    NisylKD955766g0010.1    1.8e-206    718.8   1854    393 530 1   384 1   384 MKEMCLAVAPLPFRLGNNLIFHNPLSIGSSSHMDVTRLNSMGGTTTSLYAESAEKDLSDTVSSSRSEGVPLLHMISENESNNWISGDAVVRESEDDEILSLDGDQMSCSLSVVSDSSSLCGDDFIGFEVASEIFGQNFVDAEKSICSVELIAKPGDLVESGVEDDNVSKPFAVKIEEQITDGSSSKSSQVVVQLPLNKGLSAAVSRSVFEVDYIPLWGFTSVCGRRPEMEDALATVPRFLRIPLQMLVGHRVPDGVSRCLSHLTAHFFGVYDGHGGSQVANYCRDRVHAVLAEELEKFMANLNDESIRQNCQEQWKKAFTNCFLMVDDEVGGTGNHEAVAAETVGSTAVVAIVCSSHIIVANCGDSRAVLCRGKEPTALSVDHK    MKEMCLAVAPLPFRLGNNLIFRNPPSIGSSSHMDATRLNSMGDTTTSLYAESAEKDLSDTVSSSRSEGVPLLPMISENDRNNWIAGDAVVRESEDDEILSLDGDQVSCSLSVVSDSSSLCGDDFIGFEVASDIYGQNFVDAEKSICSVELIAKPGDLVESGVEDDNVSKPFAVKLEEQITDGSSSKSSQVVVQLPLNKGLSAAVSRSVFEVDYIPLWGFTSVCGRRPEMEDALATVPRFLRIPLQMLVGDRVPDGVSRCLSHLTAHFFGVYDGHGGSQVANYCRDRVHAVLAEELEKFMANLNDESIRQNCQDQWKKAFTNCFLKVDDEVGGTGNREAVAAETVGSTAVVAIVCSSHIIVANCGDSRAVLCRGKEPMALSVDHK    MKEMCLAVAPLPFRLGNNLIFHNPLSIGSSSHMDVTRLNSMGGTTTSLYAESAEKDLSDTVSSSRSEGVPLLHMISENESNNWISGDAVVRESEDDEILSLDGDQMSCSLSVVSDSSSLCGDDFIGFEVASEIFGQNFVDAEKSICSVELIAKPGDLVESGVEDDNVSKPFAVKIEEQITDGSSSKSSQVVVQLPLNKGLSAAVSRSVFEVDYIPLWGFTSVCGRRPEMEDALATVPRFLRIPLQMLVGHRVPDGVSRCLSHLTAHFFGVYDGHGGSQVANYCRDRVHAVLAEELEKFMANLNDESIRQNCQEQWKKAFTNCFLMVDDEVGGTGNHEAVAAETVGSTAVVAIVCSSHIIVANCGDSRAVLCRGKEPTALSVDHKVSETVVLV*   MKEMCLAVAPLPFRLGNNLIFRNPPSIGSSSHMDATRLNSMGDTTTSLYAESAEKDLSDTVSSSRSEGVPLLPMISENDRNNWIAGDAVVRESEDDEILSLDGDQVSCSLSVVSDSSSLCGDDFIGFEVASDIYGQNFVDAEKSICSVELIAKPGDLVESGVEDDNVSKPFAVKLEEQITDGSSSKSSQVVVQLPLNKGLSAAVSRSVFEVDYIPLWGFTSVCGRRPEMEDALATVPRFLRIPLQMLVGDRVPDGVSRCLSHLTAHFFGVYDGHGGSQVANYCRDRVHAVLAEELEKFMANLNDESIRQNCQDQWKKAFTNCFLKVDDEVGGTGNREAVAAETVGSTAVVAIVCSSHIIVANCGDSRAVLCRGKEPMALSVDHKPNREDEYARIEAAGGKVIQWNGHRVFGVLAMSRSIGDRYLKPWIIPDPEVMFIPRTKDDECLILASDGLWDVMSNEEACELARKRILLWHKKNGVTLTLERGQGIDPAAQAAAECLSNRATQKGSKDNITVIVVDLKAQRKFKSKT  718.8   1854    384 95.6    367 17  374 0   0   97.4    0   21HR2LP9VA7GD29HP5EDSR4SA20MV25ED1FY40IL74HD62ED11MK10HR40TM7   95.6    1.8e-206    97.7
gene.71087.0.0.p1   transcript:OIT01688 transcript:OIT01688 3.8e-101    367.9   943 190 639 1   189 451 639 DRGISHAELNWPTRLKIIQGVASGMSFLHSEFASYVVPHGNLKSSNILLTEKYEPLLSDYAFYPLINNTQTVQCLFAYKSPEALQNQQISPRSDVYCLGIIILEILTGKFPSQYLNNQKGGTDIVQWVQSAIVDNRESELIDQEIANATDSSEQMVKLLHVGAACTVSDPDERIDMKEASRRIEEISLI   DRGISHAELNWPTRLKIIQGVASGMSFLHSEFASYVVPHGNLKSSNILLTEKYEPLLSDYAFYPLINNTQTVQCLFAYKSPEAIQNEQISPKSDVYCLGIIILEILTGKFPSQYLNNQKGGTDVVQWVQSAIAENRESELIDQEIANATDSIEQMVKLLHVGAACTVSDPDKRIDMKEASRRIEEISLI   DRGISHAELNWPTRLKIIQGVASGMSFLHSEFASYVVPHGNLKSSNILLTEKYEPLLSDYAFYPLINNTQTVQCLFAYKSPEALQNQQISPRSDVYCLGIIILEILTGKFPSQYLNNQKGGTDIVQWVQSAIVDNRESELIDQEIANATDSSEQMVKLLHVGAACTVSDPDERIDMKEASRRIEEISLI*  MSSNKHGRCSPLPSSSSNLSQKLLFFYISIFFLIFLSNTPFSFSISEDEALIKFKESLKNTTALDSTWHKGSNPCDKNKKWTRVQCEGNAVEGLLLGEAGLSGEIDVDPLIALPGLRVLELANNSFSGTIPEFFLLGALKSIYIDGXXXXXXXPKDFFSKMXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXESLANLKYLMELHLESXXXXXXXXSFSQASLASIDLSNNKLQGEIPQSMSKFGSDSFKGNNELCGKQLGKECNKEKENNTFQKAPMSKLKWIILGLVVGLLLITILFKAKRKEDHFDKLGKENLDEGLHVSSSNRKSMSIRSEGGDSVHGSSRRGAGSQRGKAMGDLVLVNEEKGTFGLPDLMKAAAEVLGNGVLGSAYKAKMVNGLSVVVKRLREMNKMNRDVFDTEIRKISKLRHRNILQLLAYHYRKEEKLLVSEYVPKGSLLYLLHGDRGISHAELNWPTRLKIIQGVASGMSFLHSEFASYVVPHGNLKSSNILLTEKYEPLLSDYAFYPLINNTQTVQCLFAYKSPEAIQNEQISPKSDVYCLGIIILEILTGKFPSQYLNNQKGGTDVVQWVQSAIAENRESELIDQEIANATDSIEQMVKLLHVGAACTVSDPDKRIDMKEASRRIEEISLI 367.9   943 189 95.8    181 8   187 0   0   98.9    0   83LI2QE4RK31IV8VADE17SI19EK17   95.8    3.8e-101    99.5
gene.69001.1.1.p1   NisylKD955766g0010.1    NisylKD955766g0010.1    1.4e-294    1011.9  2615    531 530 1   530 1   530 MKEMCLAVAPLPFRLGNNLIFHNPLSIGSSSHMDVTRLNSMGGTTTSLYAESAEKDLSDTVSSSRSEGVPLLHMISENESNNWISGDAVVRESEDDEILSLDGDQMSCSLSVVSDSSSLCGDDFIGFEVASEIFGQNFVDAEKSICSVELIAKPGDLVESGVEDDNVSKPFAVKIEEQITDGSSSKSSQVVVQLPLNKGLSAAVSRSVFEVDYIPLWGFTSVCGRRPEMEDALATVPRFLRIPLQMLVGHRVPDGVSRCLSHLTAHFFGVYDGHGGSQVANYCRDRVHAVLAEELEKFMANLNDESIRQNCQEQWKKAFTNCFLMVDDEVGGTGNHEAVAAETVGSTAVVAIVCSSHIIVANCGDSRAVLCRGKEPTALSVDHKPNREDEYARIEAAGGKVIQWNGHRVFGVLAMSRSIGDRYLKPWIIPDPEVMFIPRTKDDECLILASDGLWDVMSNEEACELARKRILLWHKKNGVTLTLERGQGIDPAAQAAAECLSNRAIQKGSKDNITVIVVDLKAQRKFKSKT  MKEMCLAVAPLPFRLGNNLIFRNPPSIGSSSHMDATRLNSMGDTTTSLYAESAEKDLSDTVSSSRSEGVPLLPMISENDRNNWIAGDAVVRESEDDEILSLDGDQVSCSLSVVSDSSSLCGDDFIGFEVASDIYGQNFVDAEKSICSVELIAKPGDLVESGVEDDNVSKPFAVKLEEQITDGSSSKSSQVVVQLPLNKGLSAAVSRSVFEVDYIPLWGFTSVCGRRPEMEDALATVPRFLRIPLQMLVGDRVPDGVSRCLSHLTAHFFGVYDGHGGSQVANYCRDRVHAVLAEELEKFMANLNDESIRQNCQDQWKKAFTNCFLKVDDEVGGTGNREAVAAETVGSTAVVAIVCSSHIIVANCGDSRAVLCRGKEPMALSVDHKPNREDEYARIEAAGGKVIQWNGHRVFGVLAMSRSIGDRYLKPWIIPDPEVMFIPRTKDDECLILASDGLWDVMSNEEACELARKRILLWHKKNGVTLTLERGQGIDPAAQAAAECLSNRATQKGSKDNITVIVVDLKAQRKFKSKT  MKEMCLAVAPLPFRLGNNLIFHNPLSIGSSSHMDVTRLNSMGGTTTSLYAESAEKDLSDTVSSSRSEGVPLLHMISENESNNWISGDAVVRESEDDEILSLDGDQMSCSLSVVSDSSSLCGDDFIGFEVASEIFGQNFVDAEKSICSVELIAKPGDLVESGVEDDNVSKPFAVKIEEQITDGSSSKSSQVVVQLPLNKGLSAAVSRSVFEVDYIPLWGFTSVCGRRPEMEDALATVPRFLRIPLQMLVGHRVPDGVSRCLSHLTAHFFGVYDGHGGSQVANYCRDRVHAVLAEELEKFMANLNDESIRQNCQEQWKKAFTNCFLMVDDEVGGTGNHEAVAAETVGSTAVVAIVCSSHIIVANCGDSRAVLCRGKEPTALSVDHKPNREDEYARIEAAGGKVIQWNGHRVFGVLAMSRSIGDRYLKPWIIPDPEVMFIPRTKDDECLILASDGLWDVMSNEEACELARKRILLWHKKNGVTLTLERGQGIDPAAQAAAECLSNRAIQKGSKDNITVIVVDLKAQRKFKSKT* MKEMCLAVAPLPFRLGNNLIFRNPPSIGSSSHMDATRLNSMGDTTTSLYAESAEKDLSDTVSSSRSEGVPLLPMISENDRNNWIAGDAVVRESEDDEILSLDGDQVSCSLSVVSDSSSLCGDDFIGFEVASDIYGQNFVDAEKSICSVELIAKPGDLVESGVEDDNVSKPFAVKLEEQITDGSSSKSSQVVVQLPLNKGLSAAVSRSVFEVDYIPLWGFTSVCGRRPEMEDALATVPRFLRIPLQMLVGDRVPDGVSRCLSHLTAHFFGVYDGHGGSQVANYCRDRVHAVLAEELEKFMANLNDESIRQNCQDQWKKAFTNCFLKVDDEVGGTGNREAVAAETVGSTAVVAIVCSSHIIVANCGDSRAVLCRGKEPMALSVDHKPNREDEYARIEAAGGKVIQWNGHRVFGVLAMSRSIGDRYLKPWIIPDPEVMFIPRTKDDECLILASDGLWDVMSNEEACELARKRILLWHKKNGVTLTLERGQGIDPAAQAAAECLSNRATQKGSKDNITVIVVDLKAQRKFKSKT  1011.9  2615    530 96.6    512 18  519 0   0   97.9    0   21HR2LP9VA7GD29HP5EDSR4SA20MV25ED1FY40IL74HD62ED11MK10HR40TM127IT25 96.6    1.4e-294    99.8
```

The below file has some IDs which are similar

```
gene.69001.1.0.p1       
gene.69001.1.0.p2       
gene.69001.1.3.p1       
gene.69001.1.2.p1       
gene.69001.1.1.p1
```

By remaining only `gene.69001` the IDs become identically. I used this awk script to keep only lines of the same ID with smallest value (column 30)

```
awk '!(\$1 in min) || \$30<min[\$1] {min[\$1]=\$30; line[\$1]=\$0} END {for(k in line) print line[k]}' ${2}-ide${i}-cov${cov} > ${2}-ide${i}-cov${cov}-best-hit
```

Unfortunately, I do not know how to modify the above awk script to filter the above file that only the line remained with the lowest number in a column 30?

**Update**
As output I would like to get the following IDs with all columns.

```
chr01_pilon3.g13.t1
gene.92134.0.0.p1
gene.90968.0.2.p1
gene.96656.0.5.p2
gene.69001.1.1.p1
gene.35466.0.0.p2
gene.86248.0.0.p1
gene.9403.0.4.p1
gene.91393.0.0.p1
gene.18823.1.1.p2
gene.71087.0.0.p1
```

**Update 2**
Is there a way to keep multiple copies if the column 30 value is the same?

**Update 3**
I found new data [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/14AxXeklCUAgaVWBJHfj4zOkVfJ0WKIKk/view?usp=sharing) which unfortunately none of the below solutions works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use this `awk` to get minimum value on truncated first column value:

```sh
awk '{
   if (/^gene\./) {
      split($1, a, /\./)
      k = a[1] "." a[2]
    }
    else
       k = $1
}
!(k in min) || $30 <= min[k] {
   min[k] = $30
   if(!($1 in rec))
      ord[++n] = $1
   rec[$1] = $0
}
END {
   for (i=1; i<=n; ++i)
      print rec[ord[i]]
}' gene.txt
```

```sh
chr01_pilon3.g13.t1 trnscript:OIT01734  transcript:OIT01734 1.1e-107    389.8   1000    218 992 1   216 130 345 MDALTRHIQGDVPWCMLFADDIILIDETRAGVSERLEIWRQTLESKGFKISRSKTEYLECKFGDEPSGVGREVMLGSQAIAKRDSVRYLGSVIQGDGEIDGDVTHRIGAGWSKWRLASGVLCDKKIPHKLKGKFFRAMVRPAMFYEAECWPVKNSHIQRMKVAEMRMLRWMCGHTRLDKIKNEVIRQKVGVAPVDKKMGEARLRWFGHVRRRGPDA    MDALTRHIQGDVPWCMLFADDIVLIDETRVGVNERLEVWRQTLESKGFKLSRSKTEYLECKFSAESSEVGRDVKLGSQVIAKRDSFRYLGSVIQGEGEIDGDVTHRIGAGWSKWRLASGVLCDKKVPQKLKGKFYRAVVRPAMLYGAECWPVKNSHVQRMKVAEMRMLRWMRGLTRLDRIRNEVIREKVGVALVDEKMREARLRWYGHVRRRRPDA    MDALTRHIQGDVPWCMLFADDIILIDETRAGVSERLEIWRQTLESKGFKISRSKTEYLECKFGDEPSGVGREVMLGSQAIAKRDSVRYLGSVIQGDGEIDGDVTHRIGAGWSKWRLASGVLCDKKIPHKLKGKFFRAMVRPAMFYEAECWPVKNSHIQRMKVAEMRMLRWMCGHTRLDKIKNEVIRQKVGVAPVDKKMGEARLRWFGHVRRRGPDAR*  MKVWERVVEARVREMTSISVNQFGFMPGRSTTEAIHLVRRLVEHFRDKKKDLHMVFIDLENAYDKVPREVLWRCLEAKSVPEAYIRVIKDMYDGAKTRVRTVGGDSDHFPVVMGLHQGSALSPLLFALVMDALTRHIQGDVPWCMLFADDIVLIDETRVGVNERLEVWRQTLESKGFKLSRSKTEYLECKFSAESSEVGRDVKLGSQVIAKRDSFRYLGSVIQGEGEIDGDVTHRIGAGWSKWRLASGVLCDKKVPQKLKGKFYRAVVRPAMLYGAECWPVKNSHVQRMKVAEMRMLRWMRGLTRLDRIRNEVIREKVGVALVDEKMREARLRWYGHVRRRRPDAPVRIYKSAILGHLNSHGSQNALAGPVEAEENRQKTKKEVMEEIIQKSKFFKAQKAKDREENDELTEQLDKDFTSLVESKALLSLTQPDKINALKALVNKNISVGNVKKDEVADVPRKASIGKEKPDTYEMLVSEMALDMRARPSDRTKTPEEIAQEEKERLELLEQEXXXXXXXXXXXXXXDGNASDDNSKLVKDPRTVSGDDLGDDLEEVPRTKLGWIGEILRRKENELESEDAASSGDSDDGEDEGXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXDEEQGKTQTIKDWEQSDDDIIDTELEDDDEGFGDDAKKVVKIKDHKEENLSITVAAENKKKMQVFYGVLLQYFAVLANKKPLNSKLLNLLVKPLMEMSAVSPYFAAICARQRLQRTRAQFCEDLKNTGKSSWPSLKTIFLLRLWSMIFPCSDFRHCVMTPAILLMCEYLMRCTIISGRDIAIASFLCSLLLSVIKQSQKFCPEAIVFIQTLLMAALDRKQRSNSQLDNLMEIKELGPLLCIRSSKVEMDSLDFLTLMDLPEDSQYFHSDNYRTSMLVTVLETLQGFVNVYKELISFPEIFMLISKLLCKMAGENHIPDALREKIKDVSQLIDTKAQEHHMLRQPLKMRKKKPVPIRMLNPKFEENFVKGRDYDPDRERA    389.8   1000    216 85.6    185 31  200 0   0   92.6    0   22IV6AV2SN4IV11IL12GSDA1PS1GE3ED1MK4AV6VF9DE29IV1HQ6FY2MV5FL1EG10IV14CR1HL4KR1KR5QE5PL2KE2GR6FY6GR3 85.6    1.1e-107    99.1
gene.92134.0.0.p1   NisylASAF01033898g0006.1    NisylASAF01033898g0006.1    2.6e-302    1037.7  2682    571 548 2   570 4   548 SRDLRVAQLPLIFIGKLRQTGGESKLPSFTTVPMAFSRRXXXXXSRRRWLIPAISAAFGFLLIFIFFLSILAPSPNGNRLFHPRRRSLGDNDADTDEIEDSQSHVPARSGGVSDRDIWSSRNSKFFYGCSNASNEFLKAQDITHPNRYLSIVTSGGLNQQRTGITDAVVAARILNATLVVPKLDKSSYWKDSSGFSDIFDVDWFIKYLAKDVSIVKELPLRRGQIWSPYRMRVPRKCTDRCYINRVLPVLNKKHAVQITKFDYRLANKLDTDLQKLRCRVNYHALKFADPILGMGEKLVQRMRMRSSRFIALHLRFEPDMLAFSGCYYGGGDKERRELGKIRKKWKTLHDSDPDKARRHGRCPLTPEEVGLMLRSLGYGEDVHIYVASGEIYGGEETLTLLKALFPNFHTKDTLATKDELEPFSAFSSRMAALDFIVCDESDVFVTNNHGNMAKILAGRRRFFGHKPTIRPNGRKLYRLFLNRNYMTEKEFVYRVGKYQRGFMGEPKEVGPSWGVFHENPSSCICEKVDNATGQISHSTSRLETLSKVTSNDYDIDISENQELDMLLSD   SRDLRVAQLPLIFIGKLRQTGGESKLPSFTTVPMAFSRRXXXXXSRRRWLIPAISAAFGFLLIFIFFLSILAPSPNGNRLFHLPRRRSSGDNDADNEIEDSQSHVPAGSGGVSDRDIWSSRNSKFFYGCSNASNEFLKAQDITHPNRYLSIVTSGGLNQQRTGITDAVVAARILNATLVVPKLDKSSYWKDSSGFSDIFDVDWFIKYLAKDVSIVKELPLRRGQIWSPYRMRVPRKCTDRCYINRVLPVLNKKHAVQITKFDYRLANKLDTDLQKLRCRVNYHSLKFADPILRMGEKLVQRMRMRSSHFIALHLRFEPDMLAFSGCYYGGGDKERRELGKIRKKWKTLHDSDPDKARRHGRCPLTPEEVGLMLRSLGYGEDVHIYVASGEIYGGEETLTPLKALFPNFHTKDTLATKDELEPFSAFSSRMAALDFIVCDESDPTIRPNGRKLYRLFLNRNYMTEKEFVYRVGKYQRGFMGEPKEVGPSWGVFHENPSSCICEKVDNATVEISHSTSRLETSPKVTSNDYDTDISENPELDMLLSD   QSRDLRVAQLPLIFIGKLRQTGGESKLPSFTTVPMAFSRRXXXXXSRRRWLIPAISAAFGFLLIFIFFLSILAPSPNGNRLFHPRRRSLGDNDADTDEIEDSQSHVPARSGGVSDRDIWSSRNSKFFYGCSNASNEFLKAQDITHPNRYLSIVTSGGLNQQRTGITDAVVAARILNATLVVPKLDKSSYWKDSSGFSDIFDVDWFIKYLAKDVSIVKELPLRRGQIWSPYRMRVPRKCTDRCYINRVLPVLNKKHAVQITKFDYRLANKLDTDLQKLRCRVNYHALKFADPILGMGEKLVQRMRMRSSRFIALHLRFEPDMLAFSGCYYGGGDKERRELGKIRKKWKTLHDSDPDKARRHGRCPLTPEEVGLMLRSLGYGEDVHIYVASGEIYGGEETLTLLKALFPNFHTKDTLATKDELEPFSAFSSRMAALDFIVCDESDVFVTNNHGNMAKILAGRRRFFGHKPTIRPNGRKLYRLFLNRNYMTEKEFVYRVGKYQRGFMGEPKEVGPSWGVFHENPSSCICEKVDNATGQISHSTSRLETLSKVTSNDYDIDISENQELDMLLSD* MTLSRDLRVAQLPLIFIGKLRQTGGESKLPSFTTVPMAFSRRXXXXXSRRRWLIPAISAAFGFLLIFIFFLSILAPSPNGNRLFHLPRRRSSGDNDADNEIEDSQSHVPAGSGGVSDRDIWSSRNSKFFYGCSNASNEFLKAQDITHPNRYLSIVTSGGLNQQRTGITDAVVAARILNATLVVPKLDKSSYWKDSSGFSDIFDVDWFIKYLAKDVSIVKELPLRRGQIWSPYRMRVPRKCTDRCYINRVLPVLNKKHAVQITKFDYRLANKLDTDLQKLRCRVNYHSLKFADPILRMGEKLVQRMRMRSSHFIALHLRFEPDMLAFSGCYYGGGDKERRELGKIRKKWKTLHDSDPDKARRHGRCPLTPEEVGLMLRSLGYGEDVHIYVASGEIYGGEETLTPLKALFPNFHTKDTLATKDELEPFSAFSSRMAALDFIVCDESDPTIRPNGRKLYRLFLNRNYMTEKEFVYRVGKYQRGFMGEPKEVGPSWGVFHENPSSCICEKVDNATVEISHSTSRLETSPKVTSNDYDTDISENPELDMLLSD    1037.7  2682    570 93.2    531 13  533 3   26  93.5    0   82-L5LS6TND-11RG175AS8GR14RH91LP42V-F-V-T-N-N-H-G-N-M-A-K-I-L-A-G-R-R-R-F-F-G-H-K-66GVQE10LSSP8IT5QP8   93.2    2.6e-302    99.6
gene.96656.0.5.p2   NisylKD954897g0030.1    NisylKD954897g0030.1    7.7e-75 280.0   715 140 968 1   139 371 509 MRCKYLTLNTPMKKWELHGIAILLQSCPWVEMLHINTESAFEVYHFGLHYKNSNDFNGENYWISRPCWVLHLKTLRIHGYEWWDGDEYMLSFLQVVLKNGMVLQKIIIDFFEINSYEKLTKKLLSFPRSSREAVILFSS MRCKYLTLNTPMKKWELPGIAILLQSCPQVEMLHINTESAFEEYHFGSHFKNSNDFNGENYWISRPCWVLHLKTLRIHGYEWWDGDEYILSFLQVVLKNGMVLQKIIIDFFEINSYEKLTKKLLSFPRSSREAVILFSN MRCKYLTLNTPMKKWELHGIAILLQSCPWVEMLHINTESAFEVYHFGLHYKNSNDFNGENYWISRPCWVLHLKTLRIHGYEWWDGDEYMLSFLQVVLKNGMVLQKIIIDFFEINSYEKLTKKLLSFPRSSREAVILFSS*    MSESEGEHEENLDYDSPRYSPYSXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXSDQSYYGGKCHKTEKTDRISALPDSLILHILSSLDMGEVVRTGVLSKRWHLLWTSQQSLIFSYSGQHVNGIYKFVIFIDNTLLLCRSGMVKKFSVDFIYSKRFVRHVNRWMIFIKNKLVEELDLNLRSRGNLIEIYNLPQIMYFDVRLRHLSLCNCNLVPKEEIYWPALRDLEIGYAELNRDVIKKICSGCRALESLKFRSCYGVDYFDIDSKSVKKLVIHEYGRQNHDDADDDDDELGIYARNVTSLEICGYFHKRILVLEDVKALLDAKLDFYRNTDDYEIEREFRTDQNMLKNLLVSLQHVEKLSIGTWCLQVLTSLEIRNLPCPRMRCKYLTLNTPMKKWELPGIAILLQSCPQVEMLHINTESAFEEYHFGSHFKNSNDFNGENYWISRPCWVLHLKTLRIHGYEWWDGDEYILSFLQVVLKNGMVLQKIIIDFFEINSYEKLTKKLLSFPRSSREAVILFSNRFSSLPDSVLLHILSFLPFDDVVRTTLLCKQWRPLWSFSTSLNFIHRPKDFISLKKFASFVDKSLINLHCNNSSISKLHLDFPFKRCFSSDVTVWVLFAITHKVKELNLILSSDAEDLYKLPKRLFSNPFIEKVNWVGCKFDKVEVFRWDSLRELRIGSIEFCDDMVRKVVFGSPCLELLELDNCWGFKRLDLVGGKVSKLVVNGYNGEAVKKNSMLLDFEVVEIEAPCVKVLELKGCFRRMNNIQLKNVMSCVSVKLDFQFTKDEERVNYVDMLMGMIGSLRHVKDVMLGTWCIEVMSSWPMNILPFSMSSYECLTLHTPIQERYLPGIVRILQSSSNLRTLIIHMAPPYFEFEACFIPIVYDVYSVGGRCQLSMLSKNCGLHLKKIRICCFEGMRSGQEVLFLRDLLLVCANLEEMVIEWRSGHQNSSIRDASDEFVAESLLMVQKRSRNAVILFNN    280.0   715 139 95.0    132 7   135 0   0   97.1    0   17HP10WQ13VE4LS1YF38MI49SN  95.0    7.7e-75 99.3
gene.90968.0.2.p2   transcript:OIT02339 transcript:OIT02339 1.3e-209    729.2   1881    391 1270    1   388 881 1268    MNEEASQVANDAIGSIRTVASFCAEEKVMEMYQKKSEAPLKRGVKKGLVSGVGLGFSNFVLFCLYALAFYLGAVLVRHDKAKFSEVFKVFFALTMASIGLSFLSNLPSDLSKGKGAAASIFEILDSKPRIDSSSNEGITLDAIEGNIELQHISFRYPTRPDMQIFRDLSLSIPAGKTVALVGESGSGKSTVISLLERFYDPEQGNIYLDGVEIRKFNLRWLRQQMGLVGQEPILFNETISSNIAYGREGEVTEEEIISVAKSSNAHNFISSLPNGYKTTVGERGVHLSGGQKQRIAIARAILKDPKILLLDEATSALDTESERIVQEALDRVMVNRTTVVVAHRLTTVKNADVIAVVKNGVVAEKGTHDMLMNNPQGVYASLVALQTG    MNEEASQVANDAIGSIRTVASFCAEEKVMEMYQKKSEAPLKRGVKNGLVSGVGLGFSNFVLFCLYALAFYLGAVLVKHDKAKFSEVFKVFFALTMASIGLSVLSNLPSDLSKGKGAAASIIEILDSKPRIDSSSNEGITLDAIEGNIELQHISFRYPTRPDMQIFRDLSLSIPAGKTVALVGESGSGKSTVISLLERFYDPEQGNIYLDGVEIRKFNLRWLRQQMGLVGQEPILFNETISSNIAYGREGEVTEEEIISVAKSSNAHNFISSLPNGYKTTVGERGVQLSGGQKQRIAIARAILKDPKILLLDEATSALDTESERIVQEALDRVMVNRTTVVVAHRLTTVKNADVIAVVKNGVVAEKGTHDMLMNNPQGVYASLVALQTG    MNEEASQVANDAIGSIRTVASFCAEEKVMEMYQKKSEAPLKRGVKKGLVSGVGLGFSNFVLFCLYALAFYLGAVLVRHDKAKFSEVFKVFFALTMASIGLSFLSNLPSDLSKGKGAAASIFEILDSKPRIDSSSNEGITLDAIEGNIELQHISFRYPTRPDMQIFRDLSLSIPAGKTVALVGESGSGKSTVISLLERFYDPEQGNIYLDGVEIRKFNLRWLRQQMGLVGQEPILFNETISSNIAYGREGEVTEEEIISVAKSSNAHNFISSLPNGYKTTVGERGVHLSGGQKQRIAIARAILKDPKILLLDEATSALDTESERIVQEALDRVMVNRTTVVVAHRLTTVKNADVIAVVKNGVVAEKGTHDMLMNNPQGVYASLVALQTGAT* MAEGGEPSSARRKEEDDQKVPFYMLFAFADRTDVILMLFGTLGAIASGISKPLMSLIFGDLVNSYGKSNQSNILDQVSGISLKFVYLAIGSGIASVFQIACWVVTGERQATRIKCLYLKTILRQDIGFFDTQSATGEFIERMSGDTILVQEAMGDKVANFIMNISTFIGGFVVAFIKGWLLTLVLLTSIPATAISFGCVALVLSKMSGSGQVAYADAGKVVEQTVGGIRTVASFTGEKLAIEDYNSKLESAYSATIKQALASGLGLGTILTLIFFSYGLAIWYGAKLIIEKDYKGGDIISVIFAVMLGGSSLGQASPSLNAFSAGQAAAYKIFETIKRTPKIDPYDPSGIELEDIKGEIELKDVYFKYPARPDVQIFSGFSLYIPSGKTAALVGQSGSGKSTVISLLERFYDPEAGEILIDGVEIKKFQLKWLRQQMGLVSQEPVLFATTIRENIIYGKENASEEEIRNAIQLANAAKFIDKLPKGLDTMVGGHGTQISGGQKQRIAIARAILKDPRILLLDEATSALDVESERIVQDALSNIMVNRTTVVVAHRLTTIRNADLIAVVHLGKLVEQGTHDELIKDPEGAYSQLVQMQQKTKHVENTKGKEIEELNAPKRLSYSKNVSGRSRRFSLSGRKSASKGSSSKFSFAYDLGVSGVVDFHESIRREDGAGTSEYIADTKKKVSTQKLMSLAYLNKPELPIMLVGTVAAAINGMVFPVFGLLVSTIIKIFYESHHELRKDSRFWALMFVVIGIVVMIVSPLQNYAFGVAGAKLIQRIRSMTFSKLVYQEISWFDDPANSCGAIGARLSSDASTIRNMVGDALATLVQNISTIVTGLVIALIANWILALITIAIMPLLALQGYIQIKLLQESNNEAKLMNEEASQVANDAIGSIRTVASFCAEEKVMEMYQKKSEAPLKRGVKNGLVSGVGLGFSNFVLFCLYALAFYLGAVLVKHDKAKFSEVFKVFFALTMASIGLSVLSNLPSDLSKGKGAAASIIEILDSKPRIDSSSNEGITLDAIEGNIELQHISFRYPTRPDMQIFRDLSLSIPAGKTVALVGESGSGKSTVISLLERFYDPEQGNIYLDGVEIRKFNLRWLRQQMGLVGQEPILFNETISSNIAYGREGEVTEEEIISVAKSSNAHNFISSLPNGYKTTVGERGVQLSGGQKQRIAIARAILKDPKILLLDEATSALDTESERIVQEALDRVMVNRTTVVVAHRLTTVKNADVIAVVKNGVVAEKGTHDMLMNNPQGVYASLVALQTGTA  729.2   1881    388 98.7    383 5   384 0   0   99.0    0   45KN30RK24FV18FI164HQ102    98.7    1.3e-209    99.2
gene.69001.1.0.p1   NisylKD955766g0010.1    NisylKD955766g0010.1    1.8e-206    718.8   1854    393 530 1   384 1   384 MKEMCLAVAPLPFRLGNNLIFHNPLSIGSSSHMDVTRLNSMGGTTTSLYAESAEKDLSDTVSSSRSEGVPLLHMISENESNNWISGDAVVRESEDDEILSLDGDQMSCSLSVVSDSSSLCGDDFIGFEVASEIFGQNFVDAEKSICSVELIAKPGDLVESGVEDDNVSKPFAVKIEEQITDGSSSKSSQVVVQLPLNKGLSAAVSRSVFEVDYIPLWGFTSVCGRRPEMEDALATVPRFLRIPLQMLVGHRVPDGVSRCLSHLTAHFFGVYDGHGGSQVANYCRDRVHAVLAEELEKFMANLNDESIRQNCQEQWKKAFTNCFLMVDDEVGGTGNHEAVAAETVGSTAVVAIVCSSHIIVANCGDSRAVLCRGKEPTALSVDHK    MKEMCLAVAPLPFRLGNNLIFRNPPSIGSSSHMDATRLNSMGDTTTSLYAESAEKDLSDTVSSSRSEGVPLLPMISENDRNNWIAGDAVVRESEDDEILSLDGDQVSCSLSVVSDSSSLCGDDFIGFEVASDIYGQNFVDAEKSICSVELIAKPGDLVESGVEDDNVSKPFAVKLEEQITDGSSSKSSQVVVQLPLNKGLSAAVSRSVFEVDYIPLWGFTSVCGRRPEMEDALATVPRFLRIPLQMLVGDRVPDGVSRCLSHLTAHFFGVYDGHGGSQVANYCRDRVHAVLAEELEKFMANLNDESIRQNCQDQWKKAFTNCFLKVDDEVGGTGNREAVAAETVGSTAVVAIVCSSHIIVANCGDSRAVLCRGKEPMALSVDHK    MKEMCLAVAPLPFRLGNNLIFHNPLSIGSSSHMDVTRLNSMGGTTTSLYAESAEKDLSDTVSSSRSEGVPLLHMISENESNNWISGDAVVRESEDDEILSLDGDQMSCSLSVVSDSSSLCGDDFIGFEVASEIFGQNFVDAEKSICSVELIAKPGDLVESGVEDDNVSKPFAVKIEEQITDGSSSKSSQVVVQLPLNKGLSAAVSRSVFEVDYIPLWGFTSVCGRRPEMEDALATVPRFLRIPLQMLVGHRVPDGVSRCLSHLTAHFFGVYDGHGGSQVANYCRDRVHAVLAEELEKFMANLNDESIRQNCQEQWKKAFTNCFLMVDDEVGGTGNHEAVAAETVGSTAVVAIVCSSHIIVANCGDSRAVLCRGKEPTALSVDHKVSETVVLV*   MKEMCLAVAPLPFRLGNNLIFRNPPSIGSSSHMDATRLNSMGDTTTSLYAESAEKDLSDTVSSSRSEGVPLLPMISENDRNNWIAGDAVVRESEDDEILSLDGDQVSCSLSVVSDSSSLCGDDFIGFEVASDIYGQNFVDAEKSICSVELIAKPGDLVESGVEDDNVSKPFAVKLEEQITDGSSSKSSQVVVQLPLNKGLSAAVSRSVFEVDYIPLWGFTSVCGRRPEMEDALATVPRFLRIPLQMLVGDRVPDGVSRCLSHLTAHFFGVYDGHGGSQVANYCRDRVHAVLAEELEKFMANLNDESIRQNCQDQWKKAFTNCFLKVDDEVGGTGNREAVAAETVGSTAVVAIVCSSHIIVANCGDSRAVLCRGKEPMALSVDHKPNREDEYARIEAAGGKVIQWNGHRVFGVLAMSRSIGDRYLKPWIIPDPEVMFIPRTKDDECLILASDGLWDVMSNEEACELARKRILLWHKKNGVTLTLERGQGIDPAAQAAAECLSNRATQKGSKDNITVIVVDLKAQRKFKSKT  718.8   1854    384 95.6    367 17  374 0   0   97.4    0   21HR2LP9VA7GD29HP5EDSR4SA20MV25ED1FY40IL74HD62ED11MK10HR40TM7   95.6    1.8e-206    97.7
gene.35466.0.0.p2   NiotoAWOL01S0001629g0004.1  NiotoAWOL01S0001629g0004.1  1.0e-59 229.6   584 118 889 1   118 669 786 QKPGSDDVFMEEEVLPKPSDEEMKTEDGGWTEVKETDEEEPSVKEEEMEVTPDATIHEVPVGKGLSGALKLLQERGTLKEDIEWGGRNMDKKKSKLVGIRGEDGKKEIRIERTDEYGR  QKPGSDDVFMEEEVLPKPSDEEMKTEDGGWTEVKETEEEEPSVKEEEMEVTPDATIHEVPVGKGLSGALKLLQERGTLKEDIEWGGRNMDKKKSKLVGIRGEDGKKEIRIERTDEYGR  QKPGSDDVFMEEEVLPKPSDEEMKTEDGGWTEVKETDEEEPSVKEEEMEVTPDATIHEVPVGKGLSGALKLLQERGTLKEDIEWGGRNMDKKKSKLVGIRGEDGKKEIRIERTDEYGR  MEIDGRERSVEMRDHDDSPVKERWEDGHYDLEESGHDKSKXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXDLXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXGRDAVDKEKGXXXXXXXXXXADEXXXXXXXXXXGNRRXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXAKQEIVSYEDDDRARNNAVETAGSQSSASKLEERILKMKEERLKKKSEGASEVMAWVSKSRKIEEKRTAEKERALQLSKIFEEQDKINDEESDDEEKARLAAKELGGMKVLHGLDKVVEGGAVVLTLKDQSILAGDDINQEVDVLENVEIGEQKKRDDAYKAAKKKTGIYDDKFNDDPGFERKILPQYDDPAEEEGVTLDATGGFSVDAEKKLEELRKRIQGSSSKTLAEDLNSSGKLLSDYYTQEEMLQFKKPKKKKSLRKKEKMDLDALEVEAKSSGLGVGDLGSRNDKTRQALREEMERAEAETKSKSYQAAYAKAEEASKALRPEKTNXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXELRKSLERARKLALQKQEGLAKTFPESIASLAISRANDSTVDNPSSVSGESQENKVVFTEMEEFVWGLQLDEEEQKPGSDDVFMEEEVLPKPSDEEMKTEDGGWTEVKETEEEEPSVKEEEMEVTPDATIHEVPVGKGLSGALKLLQERGTLKEDIEWGGRNMDKKKSKLVGIRGEDGKKEIRIERTDEYGRILTPKEAFRLLSHKFHGKGPGKMKQEKRMRQYQEELKIKQMKNSDTPSLSVERMREAQAQFKTPYLVLSGNVKPGQTSDPRSGFATVEKSLPGGLTPMLGDKK   229.6   584 118 99.2    117 1   118 0   0   100.0   0   36DE81  99.2    1.0e-59 100.0
gene.86248.0.0.p1   Nitab4.5_0000420g0110.1 Nitab4.5_0000420g0110.1 Protein of unknown function DUF538  8.2e-74 276.9   707 175 140 35  174 1   140 MTSQVTENHRENAEVFTNPAICKQKSLELLEQTNMPKGLLPLDDLIEVGRNHQTGFVWLKQKKAKEHRFKKIGKLVWYDTEVTAFVEDRRMKKLTGVKSKEILIWVTISDISIQDPEFQKITFATPTGISKAFPVSAFEE    MSSQVSENHRENAEVFTDPAICKQKSLELLEQINMPKGLLPLDDLIEVGRNHQTGFVWLKQKKAKEHRFKKIGKLVWYDTEVTAFIEDRRMKKLTGVKSKEILIWVTISDISIQDPEFQKITFATPTGISKAFPVSAFEE    THFLYFPFPLSHTEPQTKRNLNPISFPFSFAFTKMTSQVTENHRENAEVFTNPAICKQKSLELLEQTNMPKGLLPLDDLIEVGRNHQTGFVWLKQKKAKEHRFKKIGKLVWYDTEVTAFVEDRRMKKLTGVKSKEILIWVTISDISIQDPEFQKITFATPTGISKAFPVSAFEE* MSSQVSENHRENAEVFTDPAICKQKSLELLEQINMPKGLLPLDDLIEVGRNHQTGFVWLKQKKAKEHRFKKIGKLVWYDTEVTAFIEDRRMKKLTGVKSKEILIWVTISDISIQDPEFQKITFATPTGISKAFPVSAFEE    276.9   707 140 96.4    135 5   139 0   0   99.3    0   1TS3TS11ND14TI52VI54    96.4    8.2e-74 80.0
gene.9403.0.4.p1    transcript:OIT35479 transcript:OIT35479 8.5e-191    667.5   1721    690 406 1   378 1   378 MLSAPRVSPPAVAVAAPARFKFPNVCVNPVNLLLLHRNVGSSCKRVVVSTKAAYSRMPMDTPGAYQLIDKESGDKFIIWGGTEDDDSSIPSKEVLSWKPLASTPXXXXXXXXXXXXXDEASTRGLTGNFGRLKFRRMRDLVRKSYTKNKERDVIDHNKHNIADASSRSSFSSYNEPDQLKEQQTLSLPRGRAKIQQLDDKKNFQKLIRVEDEDRGIAIENVSKHFAGYSIDSHAQSARVVHPGSKASASPLRGWGGGSSHYSLKRDEIFRERQNLGDENNFFSRKSFQELGCSDYMIESLRNQHFVRPSHIQAMTFGPIIAGKSCIISDQSGSGKTLAYLLPLIQRLRQEELQGLSKPSSQSPRVVVLAPTAELASQV  MLSAPRAPPPAVAVAAPARFKFQNVCGNPVNLLLLHRNVGSSCKRVVVSTKAAYSRMPMDTPGAYQLIDKESGDKFIVWGGTEDDDSSIPSKEVLSWKPLASTSPDNNHPPPTQSSSNEASTRGLTGNFGRLKFRRMRDLVRKSYTKNKERDVIDHDKHNTTDASSRSSFSSYNEPGQLKEQQTLSLPRGRAKIQQLEDRKNSQKLIRVEDEDRDIAIENVSKHFAGYSSDSHAHSARVVHPGSKASASPLRGWGGGSSHYSLKREEIFRQRRNLDDENNFFSRKSFQELGCSDYMIESLRNQHFVRPSHIQAMTFGPIIAGKSCIISDQSGSGKTLAYLLPLIQRLRQEELQGLSKPSSQSPRVVVLAPTAELASQV  MLSAPRVSPPAVAVAAPARFKFPNVCVNPVNLLLLHRNVGSSCKRVVVSTKAAYSRMPMDTPGAYQLIDKESGDKFIIWGGTEDDDSSIPSKEVLSWKPLASTPXXXXXXXXXXXXXDEASTRGLTGNFGRLKFRRMRDLVRKSYTKNKERDVIDHNKHNIADASSRSSFSSYNEPDQLKEQQTLSLPRGRAKIQQLDDKKNFQKLIRVEDEDRGIAIENVSKHFAGYSIDSHAQSARVVHPGSKASASPLRGWGGGSSHYSLKRDEIFRERQNLGDENNFFSRKSFQELGCSDYMIESLRNQHFVRPSHIQAMTFGPIIAGKSCIISDQSGSGKTLAYLLPLIQRLRQEELQGLSKPSSQSPRVVVLAPTAELASQVLSTCRSFSKSGVPFHSMVVTGGFCQRTQLENLRQELDILIATPGRFMFLIKEGYLQLTNLKCAVLDEVDILFSDEDFETAFQCLINSSPITTQYLFVTATLPMDIYNKLVESFPDCELVSGPGMHRTSPGLEEFLVDCSGDETAEKSPDTAFINKKNALLHLVEDSPVPKTIVFCNKIDSCRKVENALKRFDRKGFSIKILPFHAALDQRRRLANMEEFRRSKMENVSLFLVCTDRASRGIDFEGVDHVVLFDYPRDPSEYVRRVGRTARGAGGKGKAFIFAVGKQVSLARRIMERNKKGHPVHDVPSILT*  MLSAPRAPPPAVAVAAPARFKFQNVCGNPVNLLLLHRNVGSSCKRVVVSTKAAYSRMPMDTPGAYQLIDKESGDKFIVWGGTEDDDSSIPSKEVLSWKPLASTSPDNNHPPPTQSSSNEASTRGLTGNFGRLKFRRMRDLVRKSYTKNKERDVIDHDKHNTTDASSRSSFSSYNEPGQLKEQQTLSLPRGRAKIQQLEDRKNSQKLIRVEDEDRDIAIENVSKHFAGYSSDSHAHSARVVHPGSKASASPLRGWGGGSSHYSLKREEIFRQRRNLDDENNFFSRKSFQELGCSDYMIESLRNQHFVRPSHIQAMTFGPIIAGKSCIISDQSGSGKTLAYLLPLIQRLRQEELQGLSKPSSQSPRVVVLAPTAELASQVCQISSSIKGTFATYSPYCSATTHTKRKK  667.5   1721    378 91.0    344 34  352 0   0   93.1    0   6VASP14PQ3VG50IV25PSXPXDXNXNXHXPXPXPXTXQXSXSXSDN38ND3ITAT14DG20DE1KR2FS11GD14IS4QH30DE4EQ1QR2GD102  91.0    8.5e-191    54.8
gene.91393.0.0.p1   Solyc12g056340.2.1  Solyc12g056340.2.1 RNA helicase DEAD38  1.8e-223    775.4   2001    437 806 24  437 393 806 LPAIETVLKASNSKSAQRVPPIDVLILCPTRELASQIAAEANVLLKYHESIGVQTLVGGTRFKEDQKRLESNPCQIIVATPGRLLDHIENKSGFSTRLMGLKMLILDEADHLLDLGFRKDIEKLVDCLPRKRQSLLFSATVPKEVRRVSQLVLKREHGYVDTVGLGLETNPKVKQFYLVAPHEQHFQLVHHLLTSHISEVPDYKVIVFCTTAMMTSLMFSLLREMKMNVREIHSRKPQLYRTRISDEFKETKRVILITSDVSARGMNYPDVTLVIQIGIPVDREQYIHRLGRTGREGKEGEGILLLAPWEQYFLDDIKDLPMENWPVPHLDPRAKVKIEEAIGKMDASVKEAAYHAWLGYYNSVREIGRDKTTLVELANQFSESIGLQKPPSLFRRTALKMGLKDIPGIRIRK*  LPAIETVLKASRKKSAQRVPPIDVLILCPTRELASQIAAEANVLLKYHEGIGVQTLVGGTRFKEDQKRLECDPCQIIVATPGRLLDHIENKSGFSTRIMGLKMLILDEADHLLDLGFRKDIEKLVDCLPRRRQSLLFSATVPKEVRRISQLVLKREYDYVDTVGLGLETNPKVKQFYLVAPHEQHFQVVHHLLSSHISEVPDYKVIVFCTTAMMTSLMFSLFHEMKMNVREIHSRKPQLYRTRISDEFKETKRVILITSDVSARGMNYPDVTLVIQVGLPVDREQYIHRLGRTGREGKEGEGILLLAPWEQYFLDDIKDLPMENWPVPRLDPRVKVKMEEAMEKMDTSVKESAYHAWLGYYNSVREVGRDKTTLVELANQFSESIGLDKPPSLFRRTALKMGLKDIPGIRIRK*  MLFPADYLHVSPVLFIAAIKVQQLPAIETVLKASNSKSAQRVPPIDVLILCPTRELASQIAAEANVLLKYHESIGVQTLVGGTRFKEDQKRLESNPCQIIVATPGRLLDHIENKSGFSTRLMGLKMLILDEADHLLDLGFRKDIEKLVDCLPRKRQSLLFSATVPKEVRRVSQLVLKREHGYVDTVGLGLETNPKVKQFYLVAPHEQHFQLVHHLLTSHISEVPDYKVIVFCTTAMMTSLMFSLLREMKMNVREIHSRKPQLYRTRISDEFKETKRVILITSDVSARGMNYPDVTLVIQIGIPVDREQYIHRLGRTGREGKEGEGILLLAPWEQYFLDDIKDLPMENWPVPHLDPRAKVKIEEAIGKMDASVKEAAYHAWLGYYNSVREIGRDKTTLVELANQFSESIGLQKPPSLFRRTALKMGLKDIPGIRIRK*   MGGGPRTFPGGLNKWQWKRLHEKKARDKENRLLDQEKQLYQARIRSQIRAKLTSSGEQSDFSNEQQPNYSPVSPQDHIRGLADRFMKEGAEDLWNEDDGPVNTPQINQQSGGISESIDLRKLRDTKFNDVPRSYSFQKARNFCTNISDVFAENCRTRNPTFSDSWSRQNKFLMFGWRLVNIENRNVNNLNGFLNYRCYSVDRMNGNKLRKLDFTRNESSQSEDKLRSVGLVVKGERKAKWPRFRPKPEESXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXRSRGSVKMMSSAALGKYDMKTKKRVPLKFVEDEDDLSLHVAAIRKEVKGRSMQKIETEEDEKETILSSKRFDEYDVSPLTVKALTAAGYVQMTKVQEATLSTCLEGKDALVKARTGTGKSAAFLLPAIETVLKASRKKSAQRVPPIDVLILCPTRELASQIAAEANVLLKYHEGIGVQTLVGGTRFKEDQKRLECDPCQIIVATPGRLLDHIENKSGFSTRIMGLKMLILDEADHLLDLGFRKDIEKLVDCLPRRRQSLLFSATVPKEVRRISQLVLKREYDYVDTVGLGLETNPKVKQFYLVAPHEQHFQVVHHLLSSHISEVPDYKVIVFCTTAMMTSLMFSLFHEMKMNVREIHSRKPQLYRTRISDEFKETKRVILITSDVSARGMNYPDVTLVIQVGLPVDREQYIHRLGRTGREGKEGEGILLLAPWEQYFLDDIKDLPMENWPVPRLDPRVKVKMEEAMEKMDTSVKESAYHAWLGYYNSVREVGRDKTTLVELANQFSESIGLDKPPSLFRRTALKMGLKDIPGIRIRK*  775.4   2001    414 94.0    389 25  402 0   0   97.1    0   11NRSK36SG20SCND25LI32KR16VI8HYGD29LV5TS27LFRH53IV1IL49HR4AV3IM3IMGE3AT4AS14IV20QD26    94.0    1.8e-223    94.7
gene.69001.1.3.p1   NisylKD955766g0010.1    NisylKD955766g0010.1    1.4e-228    792.3   2045    434 530 1   420 1   420 MKEMCLAVAPLPFRLGNNLIFHNPLSIGSSSHMDVTRLNSMGGTTTSLYAESAEKDLSDTVSSSRSEGVPLLHMISENESNNWISGDAVVRESEDDEILSLDGDQMSCSLSVVSDSSSLCGDDFIGFEVASEIFGQNFVDAEKSICSVELIAKPGDLVESGVEDDNVSKPFAVKIEEQITDGSSSKSSQVVVQLPLNKGLSAAVSRSVFEVDYIPLWGFTSVCGRRPEMEDALATVPRFLRIPLQMLVGHRVPDGVSRCLSHLTAHFFGVYDGHGGSQVANYCRDRVHAVLAEELEKFMANLNDESIRQNCQEQWKKAFTNCFLMVDDEVGGTGNHEAVAAETVGSTAVVAIVCSSHIIVANCGDSRAVLCRGKEPTALSVDHKPNREDEYARIEAAGGKVIQWNGHRVFGVLAMSRSIG    MKEMCLAVAPLPFRLGNNLIFRNPPSIGSSSHMDATRLNSMGDTTTSLYAESAEKDLSDTVSSSRSEGVPLLPMISENDRNNWIAGDAVVRESEDDEILSLDGDQVSCSLSVVSDSSSLCGDDFIGFEVASDIYGQNFVDAEKSICSVELIAKPGDLVESGVEDDNVSKPFAVKLEEQITDGSSSKSSQVVVQLPLNKGLSAAVSRSVFEVDYIPLWGFTSVCGRRPEMEDALATVPRFLRIPLQMLVGDRVPDGVSRCLSHLTAHFFGVYDGHGGSQVANYCRDRVHAVLAEELEKFMANLNDESIRQNCQDQWKKAFTNCFLKVDDEVGGTGNREAVAAETVGSTAVVAIVCSSHIIVANCGDSRAVLCRGKEPMALSVDHKPNREDEYARIEAAGGKVIQWNGHRVFGVLAMSRSIG    MKEMCLAVAPLPFRLGNNLIFHNPLSIGSSSHMDVTRLNSMGGTTTSLYAESAEKDLSDTVSSSRSEGVPLLHMISENESNNWISGDAVVRESEDDEILSLDGDQMSCSLSVVSDSSSLCGDDFIGFEVASEIFGQNFVDAEKSICSVELIAKPGDLVESGVEDDNVSKPFAVKIEEQITDGSSSKSSQVVVQLPLNKGLSAAVSRSVFEVDYIPLWGFTSVCGRRPEMEDALATVPRFLRIPLQMLVGHRVPDGVSRCLSHLTAHFFGVYDGHGGSQVANYCRDRVHAVLAEELEKFMANLNDESIRQNCQEQWKKAFTNCFLMVDDEVGGTGNHEAVAAETVGSTAVVAIVCSSHIIVANCGDSRAVLCRGKEPTALSVDHKPNREDEYARIEAAGGKVIQWNGHRVFGVLAMSRSIGMFLLPTLLSSICK*  MKEMCLAVAPLPFRLGNNLIFRNPPSIGSSSHMDATRLNSMGDTTTSLYAESAEKDLSDTVSSSRSEGVPLLPMISENDRNNWIAGDAVVRESEDDEILSLDGDQVSCSLSVVSDSSSLCGDDFIGFEVASDIYGQNFVDAEKSICSVELIAKPGDLVESGVEDDNVSKPFAVKLEEQITDGSSSKSSQVVVQLPLNKGLSAAVSRSVFEVDYIPLWGFTSVCGRRPEMEDALATVPRFLRIPLQMLVGDRVPDGVSRCLSHLTAHFFGVYDGHGGSQVANYCRDRVHAVLAEELEKFMANLNDESIRQNCQDQWKKAFTNCFLKVDDEVGGTGNREAVAAETVGSTAVVAIVCSSHIIVANCGDSRAVLCRGKEPMALSVDHKPNREDEYARIEAAGGKVIQWNGHRVFGVLAMSRSIGDRYLKPWIIPDPEVMFIPRTKDDECLILASDGLWDVMSNEEACELARKRILLWHKKNGVTLTLERGQGIDPAAQAAAECLSNRATQKGSKDNITVIVVDLKAQRKFKSKT  792.3   2045    420 96.0    403 17  410 0   0   97.6    0   21HR2LP9VA7GD29HP5EDSR4SA20MV25ED1FY40IL74HD62ED11MK10HR40TM43  96.0    1.4e-228    96.8
gene.18823.1.1.p2   transcript:OIT25066 transcript:OIT25066 1.0e-56 219.5   558 115 185 1   113 72  184 MLGQMVGRIRAKPGGKLEMGEASMVEKYDRALPKLRNTTSESSRYEERPAPPGTLNVAQIREIILLHQGRADDHKGSMDINQIAQRFRVDAAQVQRILQFVSLPPEDTSKKRS   MLGQMVGRIQAKPGGKLEMGEASVVEKYDRALPKLRNTTSESSRYEERPAPPGTLNVAQIREIILLHQGRADDHKGSMDINQIAQRFRVDAAQIQRILQFVSLPPEDTSKKRS   MLGQMVGRIRAKPGGKLEMGEASMVEKYDRALPKLRNTTSESSRYEERPAPPGTLNVAQIREIILLHQGRADDHKGSMDINQIAQRFRVDAAQVQRILQFVSLPPEDTSKKRSI* MGQAFRRATGRIGSSNVDAASSQLKKPIDRTPPPVPAAIKTPSDNVAPVAGSSPKDAVGETLEERDPKFDAMLGQMVGRIQAKPGGKLEMGEASVVEKYDRALPKLRNTTSESSRYEERPAPPGTLNVAQIREIILLHQGRADDHKGSMDINQIAQRFRVDAAQIQRILQFVSLPPEDTSKKRST   219.5   558 113 97.3    110 3   113 0   0   100.0   0   9RQ13MV69VI19   97.3    1.0e-56 98.3
gene.71087.0.0.p1   transcript:OIT01688 transcript:OIT01688 3.8e-101    367.9   943 190 639 1   189 451 639 DRGISHAELNWPTRLKIIQGVASGMSFLHSEFASYVVPHGNLKSSNILLTEKYEPLLSDYAFYPLINNTQTVQCLFAYKSPEALQNQQISPRSDVYCLGIIILEILTGKFPSQYLNNQKGGTDIVQWVQSAIVDNRESELIDQEIANATDSSEQMVKLLHVGAACTVSDPDERIDMKEASRRIEEISLI   DRGISHAELNWPTRLKIIQGVASGMSFLHSEFASYVVPHGNLKSSNILLTEKYEPLLSDYAFYPLINNTQTVQCLFAYKSPEAIQNEQISPKSDVYCLGIIILEILTGKFPSQYLNNQKGGTDVVQWVQSAIAENRESELIDQEIANATDSIEQMVKLLHVGAACTVSDPDKRIDMKEASRRIEEISLI   DRGISHAELNWPTRLKIIQGVASGMSFLHSEFASYVVPHGNLKSSNILLTEKYEPLLSDYAFYPLINNTQTVQCLFAYKSPEALQNQQISPRSDVYCLGIIILEILTGKFPSQYLNNQKGGTDIVQWVQSAIVDNRESELIDQEIANATDSSEQMVKLLHVGAACTVSDPDERIDMKEASRRIEEISLI*  MSSNKHGRCSPLPSSSSNLSQKLLFFYISIFFLIFLSNTPFSFSISEDEALIKFKESLKNTTALDSTWHKGSNPCDKNKKWTRVQCEGNAVEGLLLGEAGLSGEIDVDPLIALPGLRVLELANNSFSGTIPEFFLLGALKSIYIDGXXXXXXXPKDFFSKMXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXESLANLKYLMELHLESXXXXXXXXSFSQASLASIDLSNNKLQGEIPQSMSKFGSDSFKGNNELCGKQLGKECNKEKENNTFQKAPMSKLKWIILGLVVGLLLITILFKAKRKEDHFDKLGKENLDEGLHVSSSNRKSMSIRSEGGDSVHGSSRRGAGSQRGKAMGDLVLVNEEKGTFGLPDLMKAAAEVLGNGVLGSAYKAKMVNGLSVVVKRLREMNKMNRDVFDTEIRKISKLRHRNILQLLAYHYRKEEKLLVSEYVPKGSLLYLLHGDRGISHAELNWPTRLKIIQGVASGMSFLHSEFASYVVPHGNLKSSNILLTEKYEPLLSDYAFYPLINNTQTVQCLFAYKSPEAIQNEQISPKSDVYCLGIIILEILTGKFPSQYLNNQKGGTDVVQWVQSAIAENRESELIDQEIANATDSIEQMVKLLHVGAACTVSDPDKRIDMKEASRRIEEISLI 367.9   943 189 95.8    181 8   187 0   0   98.9    0   83LI2QE4RK31IV8VADE17SI19EK17   95.8    3.8e-101    99.5
gene.69001.1.1.p1   NisylKD955766g0010.1    NisylKD955766g0010.1    1.4e-294    1011.9  2615    531 530 1   530 1   530 MKEMCLAVAPLPFRLGNNLIFHNPLSIGSSSHMDVTRLNSMGGTTTSLYAESAEKDLSDTVSSSRSEGVPLLHMISENESNNWISGDAVVRESEDDEILSLDGDQMSCSLSVVSDSSSLCGDDFIGFEVASEIFGQNFVDAEKSICSVELIAKPGDLVESGVEDDNVSKPFAVKIEEQITDGSSSKSSQVVVQLPLNKGLSAAVSRSVFEVDYIPLWGFTSVCGRRPEMEDALATVPRFLRIPLQMLVGHRVPDGVSRCLSHLTAHFFGVYDGHGGSQVANYCRDRVHAVLAEELEKFMANLNDESIRQNCQEQWKKAFTNCFLMVDDEVGGTGNHEAVAAETVGSTAVVAIVCSSHIIVANCGDSRAVLCRGKEPTALSVDHKPNREDEYARIEAAGGKVIQWNGHRVFGVLAMSRSIGDRYLKPWIIPDPEVMFIPRTKDDECLILASDGLWDVMSNEEACELARKRILLWHKKNGVTLTLERGQGIDPAAQAAAECLSNRAIQKGSKDNITVIVVDLKAQRKFKSKT  MKEMCLAVAPLPFRLGNNLIFRNPPSIGSSSHMDATRLNSMGDTTTSLYAESAEKDLSDTVSSSRSEGVPLLPMISENDRNNWIAGDAVVRESEDDEILSLDGDQVSCSLSVVSDSSSLCGDDFIGFEVASDIYGQNFVDAEKSICSVELIAKPGDLVESGVEDDNVSKPFAVKLEEQITDGSSSKSSQVVVQLPLNKGLSAAVSRSVFEVDYIPLWGFTSVCGRRPEMEDALATVPRFLRIPLQMLVGDRVPDGVSRCLSHLTAHFFGVYDGHGGSQVANYCRDRVHAVLAEELEKFMANLNDESIRQNCQDQWKKAFTNCFLKVDDEVGGTGNREAVAAETVGSTAVVAIVCSSHIIVANCGDSRAVLCRGKEPMALSVDHKPNREDEYARIEAAGGKVIQWNGHRVFGVLAMSRSIGDRYLKPWIIPDPEVMFIPRTKDDECLILASDGLWDVMSNEEACELARKRILLWHKKNGVTLTLERGQGIDPAAQAAAECLSNRATQKGSKDNITVIVVDLKAQRKFKSKT  MKEMCLAVAPLPFRLGNNLIFHNPLSIGSSSHMDVTRLNSMGGTTTSLYAESAEKDLSDTVSSSRSEGVPLLHMISENESNNWISGDAVVRESEDDEILSLDGDQMSCSLSVVSDSSSLCGDDFIGFEVASEIFGQNFVDAEKSICSVELIAKPGDLVESGVEDDNVSKPFAVKIEEQITDGSSSKSSQVVVQLPLNKGLSAAVSRSVFEVDYIPLWGFTSVCGRRPEMEDALATVPRFLRIPLQMLVGHRVPDGVSRCLSHLTAHFFGVYDGHGGSQVANYCRDRVHAVLAEELEKFMANLNDESIRQNCQEQWKKAFTNCFLMVDDEVGGTGNHEAVAAETVGSTAVVAIVCSSHIIVANCGDSRAVLCRGKEPTALSVDHKPNREDEYARIEAAGGKVIQWNGHRVFGVLAMSRSIGDRYLKPWIIPDPEVMFIPRTKDDECLILASDGLWDVMSNEEACELARKRILLWHKKNGVTLTLERGQGIDPAAQAAAECLSNRAIQKGSKDNITVIVVDLKAQRKFKSKT* MKEMCLAVAPLPFRLGNNLIFRNPPSIGSSSHMDATRLNSMGDTTTSLYAESAEKDLSDTVSSSRSEGVPLLPMISENDRNNWIAGDAVVRESEDDEILSLDGDQVSCSLSVVSDSSSLCGDDFIGFEVASDIYGQNFVDAEKSICSVELIAKPGDLVESGVEDDNVSKPFAVKLEEQITDGSSSKSSQVVVQLPLNKGLSAAVSRSVFEVDYIPLWGFTSVCGRRPEMEDALATVPRFLRIPLQMLVGDRVPDGVSRCLSHLTAHFFGVYDGHGGSQVANYCRDRVHAVLAEELEKFMANLNDESIRQNCQDQWKKAFTNCFLKVDDEVGGTGNREAVAAETVGSTAVVAIVCSSHIIVANCGDSRAVLCRGKEPMALSVDHKPNREDEYARIEAAGGKVIQWNGHRVFGVLAMSRSIGDRYLKPWIIPDPEVMFIPRTKDDECLILASDGLWDVMSNEEACELARKRILLWHKKNGVTLTLERGQGIDPAAQAAAECLSNRATQKGSKDNITVIVVDLKAQRKFKSKT  1011.9  2615    530 96.6    512 18  519 0   0   97.9    0   21HR2LP9VA7GD29HP5EDSR4SA20MV25ED1FY40IL74HD62ED11MK10HR40TM127IT25 96.6    1.4e-294    99.8
gene.69001.9.9.p1   NisylKD955766g0010.1    NisylKD955766g0010.1    1.4e-294    1011.9  2615    531 530 1   530 1   530 MKEMCLAVAPLPFRLGNNLIFHNPLSIGSSSHMDVTRLNSMGGTTTSLYAESAEKDLSDTVSSSRSEGVPLLHMISENESNNWISGDAVVRESEDDEILSLDGDQMSCSLSVVSDSSSLCGDDFIGFEVASEIFGQNFVDAEKSICSVELIAKPGDLVESGVEDDNVSKPFAVKIEEQITDGSSSKSSQVVVQLPLNKGLSAAVSRSVFEVDYIPLWGFTSVCGRRPEMEDALATVPRFLRIPLQMLVGHRVPDGVSRCLSHLTAHFFGVYDGHGGSQVANYCRDRVHAVLAEELEKFMANLNDESIRQNCQEQWKKAFTNCFLMVDDEVGGTGNHEAVAAETVGSTAVVAIVCSSHIIVANCGDSRAVLCRGKEPTALSVDHKPNREDEYARIEAAGGKVIQWNGHRVFGVLAMSRSIGDRYLKPWIIPDPEVMFIPRTKDDECLILASDGLWDVMSNEEACELARKRILLWHKKNGVTLTLERGQGIDPAAQAAAECLSNRAIQKGSKDNITVIVVDLKAQRKFKSKT  MKEMCLAVAPLPFRLGNNLIFRNPPSIGSSSHMDATRLNSMGDTTTSLYAESAEKDLSDTVSSSRSEGVPLLPMISENDRNNWIAGDAVVRESEDDEILSLDGDQVSCSLSVVSDSSSLCGDDFIGFEVASDIYGQNFVDAEKSICSVELIAKPGDLVESGVEDDNVSKPFAVKLEEQITDGSSSKSSQVVVQLPLNKGLSAAVSRSVFEVDYIPLWGFTSVCGRRPEMEDALATVPRFLRIPLQMLVGDRVPDGVSRCLSHLTAHFFGVYDGHGGSQVANYCRDRVHAVLAEELEKFMANLNDESIRQNCQDQWKKAFTNCFLKVDDEVGGTGNREAVAAETVGSTAVVAIVCSSHIIVANCGDSRAVLCRGKEPMALSVDHKPNREDEYARIEAAGGKVIQWNGHRVFGVLAMSRSIGDRYLKPWIIPDPEVMFIPRTKDDECLILASDGLWDVMSNEEACELARKRILLWHKKNGVTLTLERGQGIDPAAQAAAECLSNRATQKGSKDNITVIVVDLKAQRKFKSKT  MKEMCLAVAPLPFRLGNNLIFHNPLSIGSSSHMDVTRLNSMGGTTTSLYAESAEKDLSDTVSSSRSEGVPLLHMISENESNNWISGDAVVRESEDDEILSLDGDQMSCSLSVVSDSSSLCGDDFIGFEVASEIFGQNFVDAEKSICSVELIAKPGDLVESGVEDDNVSKPFAVKIEEQITDGSSSKSSQVVVQLPLNKGLSAAVSRSVFEVDYIPLWGFTSVCGRRPEMEDALATVPRFLRIPLQMLVGHRVPDGVSRCLSHLTAHFFGVYDGHGGSQVANYCRDRVHAVLAEELEKFMANLNDESIRQNCQEQWKKAFTNCFLMVDDEVGGTGNHEAVAAETVGSTAVVAIVCSSHIIVANCGDSRAVLCRGKEPTALSVDHKPNREDEYARIEAAGGKVIQWNGHRVFGVLAMSRSIGDRYLKPWIIPDPEVMFIPRTKDDECLILASDGLWDVMSNEEACELARKRILLWHKKNGVTLTLERGQGIDPAAQAAAECLSNRAIQKGSKDNITVIVVDLKAQRKFKSKT* MKEMCLAVAPLPFRLGNNLIFRNPPSIGSSSHMDATRLNSMGDTTTSLYAESAEKDLSDTVSSSRSEGVPLLPMISENDRNNWIAGDAVVRESEDDEILSLDGDQVSCSLSVVSDSSSLCGDDFIGFEVASDIYGQNFVDAEKSICSVELIAKPGDLVESGVEDDNVSKPFAVKLEEQITDGSSSKSSQVVVQLPLNKGLSAAVSRSVFEVDYIPLWGFTSVCGRRPEMEDALATVPRFLRIPLQMLVGDRVPDGVSRCLSHLTAHFFGVYDGHGGSQVANYCRDRVHAVLAEELEKFMANLNDESIRQNCQDQWKKAFTNCFLKVDDEVGGTGNREAVAAETVGSTAVVAIVCSSHIIVANCGDSRAVLCRGKEPMALSVDHKPNREDEYARIEAAGGKVIQWNGHRVFGVLAMSRSIGDRYLKPWIIPDPEVMFIPRTKDDECLILASDGLWDVMSNEEACELARKRILLWHKKNGVTLTLERGQGIDPAAQAAAECLSNRATQKGSKDNITVIVVDLKAQRKFKSKT  1011.9  2615    530 96.6    512 18  519 0   0   97.9    0   21HR2LP9VA7GD29HP5EDSR4SA20MV25ED1FY40IL74HD62ED11MK10HR40TM127IT25 96.6    1.4e-294    99.8
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/224400/discussion-on-answer-by-anubhava-filtering-file-according-to-the-lowest-number-i).

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your question, and you want to keep the unique record with the lowest value in *Field 30* for the records with a common prefix in *Field 1*, e.g. `gene.90968` or `gene.69001`, which would correspond to the values:

```
gene.90968 - 0.0e+00
gene.18823 - 1.0e-56
gene.9403 - 8.5e-191
gene.35466 - 1.0e-59
gene.91393 - 0
gene.92134 - 2.6e-302
gene.71087 - 3.8e-101
gene.69001 - 1.4e-294
gene.96656 - 7.7e-75
gene.86248 - 0
```

Then you can `split()` field-1 on `'.'`, and using the first and second parts for the prefix (as shown above) for the array index, maintain two arrays (1) holding the entire record that corresponds to the lowest value of field-30 and (2) a second array holding field-30, you could do the following only considering records starting with `"gene"`:

```
awk ' /^gene/ {
    split ($1,a,".")
    if (a[1] SUBSEP a[2] in arr) {
        if ($30 < v[a[1],a[2]]) {
            arr[a[1],a[2]]=$0
            v[a[1],a[2]]=$30
        }
        else if ($30 == v[a[1],a[2]]) {       ## handle prefix where field-30
            arr[a[1],a[2],++n[a[1],a[2]]]=$0  ## are equal between the two
        }
    }
    else {
        arr[a[1],a[2]]=$0
        v[a[1],a[2]]=$30
    }
    next
}
{ print }
END { for(i in arr) print arr[i] }' file
```

All other records beginning in something other than `"gene"` are output unchanged. The order of the records will change.

Which would output the `10` unique records with the lowest value in field-30 for the common prefix.

**Output**

```
gene.90968.0.2.p1   transcript:OIT02339 transcript:OIT02339 0.0e+00 1592.0  4121    887 1270    1   881 1   880 MAEGGEPSSARRKEEENDQKIPFYMLFAFADRTDVILMLFGTFGAIASGISQPLMSLIFGDLVNSYGKSDQSNILDQVSGISLKFVYLAIGSGIASVFQIACWVVTGERQATRIKCLYLKTILRQDIGFFDTQSATGEFIEKMSGDTILVQEAMGDKVANFIMNVSTSIGGFVVAFIKGWLLTLVLLTSIPATAISFGCVALVLSKMSGSGQVAYADAGKVVEQTVGGIRTVASFTGEKLAIEDYNSKLESADSATVKQALASGLGLGTILTLIFFSYGLAIWYGAKLIIEKDYKGGDIISVIFAVMLGGSSLGQASPSLNAFSAGQAAAYKIFETIKRTPKIDPYDPSGVKLEDIKGEIELKDVYFKYPARPDVQIFSGFSLYIPSGKTAALVGQSGSGKSTVISLLERFYDPEAGEILIDGVEIKKFQLEWLRQQMGLVSQEPVLFATTIRENIIYGKENASEEEIRNAIQLANAAKFIDKLPKGLDTMVGGHGTQISGGQKQRIAIARAILKDPRILLLDEATSALDVESERTVQDALSNIMINRTTVVVAHRLTTIRNADLIAVVHLGKLVEQGTHDELIKDPEGAYSQLVQMQQKTKHVENTKGKEIEDLNAQKRLSYSKNFSGRSRRFSLSGRKSASKGSSSKFSFAYDLGVSDVVDFHESIRREDEAGTSEYTVDTTKKVSTQKLMSLAYLNKPELPIMLVGTVAAAINGMVYPVFGLLVSTIIKIFYESHHELRKDSRFWALMFVVIGIVVMIVSPLQNYAFGVAGAKLIQRIRSMMFSKLVYQEISWFDDPANSCGAIGARLSSDASTIRNMVGDALATLVQNISTIVTGLVIALIANWILALITIAIMPVLALQGYIQIKLLQESNVEAKL   MAEGGEPSSARRKEEDDQKVPFYMLFAFADRTDVILMLFGTLGAIASGISKPLMSLIFGDLVNSYGKSNQSNILDQVSGISLKFVYLAIGSGIASVFQIACWVVTGERQATRIKCLYLKTILRQDIGFFDTQSATGEFIERMSGDTILVQEAMGDKVANFIMNISTFIGGFVVAFIKGWLLTLVLLTSIPATAISFGCVALVLSKMSGSGQVAYADAGKVVEQTVGGIRTVASFTGEKLAIEDYNSKLESAYSATIKQALASGLGLGTILTLIFFSYGLAIWYGAKLIIEKDYKGGDIISVIFAVMLGGSSLGQASPSLNAFSAGQAAAYKIFETIKRTPKIDPYDPSGIELEDIKGEIELKDVYFKYPARPDVQIFSGFSLYIPSGKTAALVGQSGSGKSTVISLLERFYDPEAGEILIDGVEIKKFQLKWLRQQMGLVSQEPVLFATTIRENIIYGKENASEEEIRNAIQLANAAKFIDKLPKGLDTMVGGHGTQISGGQKQRIAIARAILKDPRILLLDEATSALDVESERIVQDALSNIMVNRTTVVVAHRLTTIRNADLIAVVHLGKLVEQGTHDELIKDPEGAYSQLVQMQQKTKHVENTKGKEIEELNAPKRLSYSKNVSGRSRRFSLSGRKSASKGSSSKFSFAYDLGVSGVVDFHESIRREDGAGTSEYIADTKKKVSTQKLMSLAYLNKPELPIMLVGTVAAAINGMVFPVFGLLVSTIIKIFYESHHELRKDSRFWALMFVVIGIVVMIVSPLQNYAFGVAGAKLIQRIRSMTFSKLVYQEISWFDDPANSCGAIGARLSSDASTIRNMVGDALATLVQNISTIVTGLVIALIANWILALITIAIMPLLALQGYIQIKLLQESNNEAKL    MAEGGEPSSARRKEEENDQKIPFYMLFAFADRTDVILMLFGTFGAIASGISQPLMSLIFGDLVNSYGKSDQSNILDQVSGISLKFVYLAIGSGIASVFQIACWVVTGERQATRIKCLYLKTILRQDIGFFDTQSATGEFIEKMSGDTILVQEAMGDKVANFIMNVSTSIGGFVVAFIKGWLLTLVLLTSIPATAISFGCVALVLSKMSGSGQVAYADAGKVVEQTVGGIRTVASFTGEKLAIEDYNSKLESADSATVKQALASGLGLGTILTLIFFSYGLAIWYGAKLIIEKDYKGGDIISVIFAVMLGGSSLGQASPSLNAFSAGQAAAYKIFETIKRTPKIDPYDPSGVKLEDIKGEIELKDVYFKYPARPDVQIFSGFSLYIPSGKTAALVGQSGSGKSTVISLLERFYDPEAGEILIDGVEIKKFQLEWLRQQMGLVSQEPVLFATTIRENIIYGKENASEEEIRNAIQLANAAKFIDKLPKGLDTMVGGHGTQISGGQKQRIAIARAILKDPRILLLDEATSALDVESERTVQDALSNIMINRTTVVVAHRLTTIRNADLIAVVHLGKLVEQGTHDELIKDPEGAYSQLVQMQQKTKHVENTKGKEIEDLNAQKRLSYSKNFSGRSRRFSLSGRKSASKGSSSKFSFAYDLGVSDVVDFHESIRREDEAGTSEYTVDTTKKVSTQKLMSLAYLNKPELPIMLVGTVAAAINGMVYPVFGLLVSTIIKIFYESHHELRKDSRFWALMFVVIGIVVMIVSPLQNYAFGVAGAKLIQRIRSMMFSKLVYQEISWFDDPANSCGAIGARLSSDASTIRNMVGDALATLVQNISTIVTGLVIALIANWILALITIAIMPVLALQGYIQIKLLQESNVEAKLPVVMF* MAEGGEPSSARRKEEDDQKVPFYMLFAFADRTDVILMLFGTLGAIASGISKPLMSLIFGDLVNSYGKSNQSNILDQVSGISLKFVYLAIGSGIASVFQIACWVVTGERQATRIKCLYLKTILRQDIGFFDTQSATGEFIERMSGDTILVQEAMGDKVANFIMNISTFIGGFVVAFIKGWLLTLVLLTSIPATAISFGCVALVLSKMSGSGQVAYADAGKVVEQTVGGIRTVASFTGEKLAIEDYNSKLESAYSATIKQALASGLGLGTILTLIFFSYGLAIWYGAKLIIEKDYKGGDIISVIFAVMLGGSSLGQASPSLNAFSAGQAAAYKIFETIKRTPKIDPYDPSGIELEDIKGEIELKDVYFKYPARPDVQIFSGFSLYIPSGKTAALVGQSGSGKSTVISLLERFYDPEAGEILIDGVEIKKFQLKWLRQQMGLVSQEPVLFATTIRENIIYGKENASEEEIRNAIQLANAAKFIDKLPKGLDTMVGGHGTQISGGQKQRIAIARAILKDPRILLLDEATSALDVESERIVQDALSNIMVNRTTVVVAHRLTTIRNADLIAVVHLGKLVEQGTHDELIKDPEGAYSQLVQMQQKTKHVENTKGKEIEELNAPKRLSYSKNVSGRSRRFSLSGRKSASKGSSSKFSFAYDLGVSGVVDFHESIRREDGAGTSEYIADTKKKVSTQKLMSLAYLNKPELPIMLVGTVAAAINGMVFPVFGLLVSTIIKIFYESHHELRKDSRFWALMFVVIGIVVMIVSPLQNYAFGVAGAKLIQRIRSMTFSKLVYQEISWFDDPANSCGAIGARLSSDASTIRNMVGDALATLVQNISTIVTGLVIALIANWILALITIAIMPLLALQGYIQIKLLQESNNEAKLMNEEASQVANDAIGSIRTVASFCAEEKVMEMYQKKSEAPLKRGVKNGLVSGVGLGFSNFVLFCLYALAFYLGAVLVKHDKAKFSEVFKVFFALTMASIGLSVLSNLPSDLSKGKGAAASIIEILDSKPRIDSSSNEGITLDAIEGNIELQHISFRYPTRPDMQIFRDLSLSIPAGKTVALVGESGSGKSTVISLLERFYDPEQGNIYLDGVEIRKFNLRWLRQQMGLVGQEPILFNETISSNIAYGREGEVTEEEIISVAKSSNAHNFISSLPNGYKTTVGERGVQLSGGQKQRIAIARAILKDPKILLLDEATSALDTESERIVQEALDRVMVNRTTVVVAHRLTTVKNADVIAVVKNGVVAEKGTHDMLMNNPQGVYASLVALQTGTA  1592.0  4121    881 96.8    853 27  867 1   1   98.4    0   15EDN-3IV21FL8QK17DN71KR22VI2SF84DY3VI93VIKE79EK103TI9IV67DE3QP8FV32DG12EG6TIVA2TK35YF64MT74VL16VN4 96.8    0.0e+00 99.3
gene.18823.1.1.p2   transcript:OIT25066 transcript:OIT25066 1.0e-56 219.5   558 115 185 1   113 72  184 MLGQMVGRIRAKPGGKLEMGEASMVEKYDRALPKLRNTTSESSRYEERPAPPGTLNVAQIREIILLHQGRADDHKGSMDINQIAQRFRVDAAQVQRILQFVSLPPEDTSKKRS   MLGQMVGRIQAKPGGKLEMGEASVVEKYDRALPKLRNTTSESSRYEERPAPPGTLNVAQIREIILLHQGRADDHKGSMDINQIAQRFRVDAAQIQRILQFVSLPPEDTSKKRS   MLGQMVGRIRAKPGGKLEMGEASMVEKYDRALPKLRNTTSESSRYEERPAPPGTLNVAQIREIILLHQGRADDHKGSMDINQIAQRFRVDAAQVQRILQFVSLPPEDTSKKRSI* MGQAFRRATGRIGSSNVDAASSQLKKPIDRTPPPVPAAIKTPSDNVAPVAGSSPKDAVGETLEERDPKFDAMLGQMVGRIQAKPGGKLEMGEASVVEKYDRALPKLRNTTSESSRYEERPAPPGTLNVAQIREIILLHQGRADDHKGSMDINQIAQRFRVDAAQIQRILQFVSLPPEDTSKKRST   219.5   558 113 97.3    110 3   113 0   0   100.0   0   9RQ13MV69VI19   97.3    1.0e-56 98.3
gene.9403.0.4.p1    transcript:OIT35479 transcript:OIT35479 8.5e-191    667.5   1721    690 406 1   378 1   378 MLSAPRVSPPAVAVAAPARFKFPNVCVNPVNLLLLHRNVGSSCKRVVVSTKAAYSRMPMDTPGAYQLIDKESGDKFIIWGGTEDDDSSIPSKEVLSWKPLASTPXXXXXXXXXXXXXDEASTRGLTGNFGRLKFRRMRDLVRKSYTKNKERDVIDHNKHNIADASSRSSFSSYNEPDQLKEQQTLSLPRGRAKIQQLDDKKNFQKLIRVEDEDRGIAIENVSKHFAGYSIDSHAQSARVVHPGSKASASPLRGWGGGSSHYSLKRDEIFRERQNLGDENNFFSRKSFQELGCSDYMIESLRNQHFVRPSHIQAMTFGPIIAGKSCIISDQSGSGKTLAYLLPLIQRLRQEELQGLSKPSSQSPRVVVLAPTAELASQV  MLSAPRAPPPAVAVAAPARFKFQNVCGNPVNLLLLHRNVGSSCKRVVVSTKAAYSRMPMDTPGAYQLIDKESGDKFIVWGGTEDDDSSIPSKEVLSWKPLASTSPDNNHPPPTQSSSNEASTRGLTGNFGRLKFRRMRDLVRKSYTKNKERDVIDHDKHNTTDASSRSSFSSYNEPGQLKEQQTLSLPRGRAKIQQLEDRKNSQKLIRVEDEDRDIAIENVSKHFAGYSSDSHAHSARVVHPGSKASASPLRGWGGGSSHYSLKREEIFRQRRNLDDENNFFSRKSFQELGCSDYMIESLRNQHFVRPSHIQAMTFGPIIAGKSCIISDQSGSGKTLAYLLPLIQRLRQEELQGLSKPSSQSPRVVVLAPTAELASQV  MLSAPRVSPPAVAVAAPARFKFPNVCVNPVNLLLLHRNVGSSCKRVVVSTKAAYSRMPMDTPGAYQLIDKESGDKFIIWGGTEDDDSSIPSKEVLSWKPLASTPXXXXXXXXXXXXXDEASTRGLTGNFGRLKFRRMRDLVRKSYTKNKERDVIDHNKHNIADASSRSSFSSYNEPDQLKEQQTLSLPRGRAKIQQLDDKKNFQKLIRVEDEDRGIAIENVSKHFAGYSIDSHAQSARVVHPGSKASASPLRGWGGGSSHYSLKRDEIFRERQNLGDENNFFSRKSFQELGCSDYMIESLRNQHFVRPSHIQAMTFGPIIAGKSCIISDQSGSGKTLAYLLPLIQRLRQEELQGLSKPSSQSPRVVVLAPTAELASQVLSTCRSFSKSGVPFHSMVVTGGFCQRTQLENLRQELDILIATPGRFMFLIKEGYLQLTNLKCAVLDEVDILFSDEDFETAFQCLINSSPITTQYLFVTATLPMDIYNKLVESFPDCELVSGPGMHRTSPGLEEFLVDCSGDETAEKSPDTAFINKKNALLHLVEDSPVPKTIVFCNKIDSCRKVENALKRFDRKGFSIKILPFHAALDQRRRLANMEEFRRSKMENVSLFLVCTDRASRGIDFEGVDHVVLFDYPRDPSEYVRRVGRTARGAGGKGKAFIFAVGKQVSLARRIMERNKKGHPVHDVPSILT*  MLSAPRAPPPAVAVAAPARFKFQNVCGNPVNLLLLHRNVGSSCKRVVVSTKAAYSRMPMDTPGAYQLIDKESGDKFIVWGGTEDDDSSIPSKEVLSWKPLASTSPDNNHPPPTQSSSNEASTRGLTGNFGRLKFRRMRDLVRKSYTKNKERDVIDHDKHNTTDASSRSSFSSYNEPGQLKEQQTLSLPRGRAKIQQLEDRKNSQKLIRVEDEDRDIAIENVSKHFAGYSSDSHAHSARVVHPGSKASASPLRGWGGGSSHYSLKREEIFRQRRNLDDENNFFSRKSFQELGCSDYMIESLRNQHFVRPSHIQAMTFGPIIAGKSCIISDQSGSGKTLAYLLPLIQRLRQEELQGLSKPSSQSPRVVVLAPTAELASQVCQISSSIKGTFATYSPYCSATTHTKRKK  667.5   1721    378 91.0    344 34  352 0   0   93.1    0   6VASP14PQ3VG50IV25PSXPXDXNXNXHXPXPXPXTXQXSXSXSDN38ND3ITAT14DG20DE1KR2FS11GD14IS4QH30DE4EQ1QR2GD102  91.0    8.5e-191    54.8
gene.35466.0.0.p2   NiotoAWOL01S0001629g0004.1  NiotoAWOL01S0001629g0004.1  1.0e-59 229.6   584 118 889 1   118 669 786 QKPGSDDVFMEEEVLPKPSDEEMKTEDGGWTEVKETDEEEPSVKEEEMEVTPDATIHEVPVGKGLSGALKLLQERGTLKEDIEWGGRNMDKKKSKLVGIRGEDGKKEIRIERTDEYGR  QKPGSDDVFMEEEVLPKPSDEEMKTEDGGWTEVKETEEEEPSVKEEEMEVTPDATIHEVPVGKGLSGALKLLQERGTLKEDIEWGGRNMDKKKSKLVGIRGEDGKKEIRIERTDEYGR  QKPGSDDVFMEEEVLPKPSDEEMKTEDGGWTEVKETDEEEPSVKEEEMEVTPDATIHEVPVGKGLSGALKLLQERGTLKEDIEWGGRNMDKKKSKLVGIRGEDGKKEIRIERTDEYGR  MEIDGRERSVEMRDHDDSPVKERWEDGHYDLEESGHDKSKXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXDLXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXGRDAVDKEKGXXXXXXXXXXADEXXXXXXXXXXGNRRXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXAKQEIVSYEDDDRARNNAVETAGSQSSASKLEERILKMKEERLKKKSEGASEVMAWVSKSRKIEEKRTAEKERALQLSKIFEEQDKINDEESDDEEKARLAAKELGGMKVLHGLDKVVEGGAVVLTLKDQSILAGDDINQEVDVLENVEIGEQKKRDDAYKAAKKKTGIYDDKFNDDPGFERKILPQYDDPAEEEGVTLDATGGFSVDAEKKLEELRKRIQGSSSKTLAEDLNSSGKLLSDYYTQEEMLQFKKPKKKKSLRKKEKMDLDALEVEAKSSGLGVGDLGSRNDKTRQALREEMERAEAETKSKSYQAAYAKAEEASKALRPEKTNXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXELRKSLERARKLALQKQEGLAKTFPESIASLAISRANDSTVDNPSSVSGESQENKVVFTEMEEFVWGLQLDEEEQKPGSDDVFMEEEVLPKPSDEEMKTEDGGWTEVKETEEEEPSVKEEEMEVTPDATIHEVPVGKGLSGALKLLQERGTLKEDIEWGGRNMDKKKSKLVGIRGEDGKKEIRIERTDEYGRILTPKEAFRLLSHKFHGKGPGKMKQEKRMRQYQEELKIKQMKNSDTPSLSVERMREAQAQFKTPYLVLSGNVKPGQTSDPRSGFATVEKSLPGGLTPMLGDKK   229.6   584 118 99.2    117 1   118 0   0   100.0   0   36DE81  99.2    1.0e-59 100.0
gene.91393.0.0.p1   Solyc12g056340.2.1  Solyc12g056340.2.1 RNA helicase DEAD38  1.8e-223    775.4   2001    437 806 24  437 393 806 LPAIETVLKASNSKSAQRVPPIDVLILCPTRELASQIAAEANVLLKYHESIGVQTLVGGTRFKEDQKRLESNPCQIIVATPGRLLDHIENKSGFSTRLMGLKMLILDEADHLLDLGFRKDIEKLVDCLPRKRQSLLFSATVPKEVRRVSQLVLKREHGYVDTVGLGLETNPKVKQFYLVAPHEQHFQLVHHLLTSHISEVPDYKVIVFCTTAMMTSLMFSLLREMKMNVREIHSRKPQLYRTRISDEFKETKRVILITSDVSARGMNYPDVTLVIQIGIPVDREQYIHRLGRTGREGKEGEGILLLAPWEQYFLDDIKDLPMENWPVPHLDPRAKVKIEEAIGKMDASVKEAAYHAWLGYYNSVREIGRDKTTLVELANQFSESIGLQKPPSLFRRTALKMGLKDIPGIRIRK*  LPAIETVLKASRKKSAQRVPPIDVLILCPTRELASQIAAEANVLLKYHEGIGVQTLVGGTRFKEDQKRLECDPCQIIVATPGRLLDHIENKSGFSTRIMGLKMLILDEADHLLDLGFRKDIEKLVDCLPRRRQSLLFSATVPKEVRRISQLVLKREYDYVDTVGLGLETNPKVKQFYLVAPHEQHFQVVHHLLSSHISEVPDYKVIVFCTTAMMTSLMFSLFHEMKMNVREIHSRKPQLYRTRISDEFKETKRVILITSDVSARGMNYPDVTLVIQVGLPVDREQYIHRLGRTGREGKEGEGILLLAPWEQYFLDDIKDLPMENWPVPRLDPRVKVKMEEAMEKMDTSVKESAYHAWLGYYNSVREVGRDKTTLVELANQFSESIGLDKPPSLFRRTALKMGLKDIPGIRIRK*  MLFPADYLHVSPVLFIAAIKVQQLPAIETVLKASNSKSAQRVPPIDVLILCPTRELASQIAAEANVLLKYHESIGVQTLVGGTRFKEDQKRLESNPCQIIVATPGRLLDHIENKSGFSTRLMGLKMLILDEADHLLDLGFRKDIEKLVDCLPRKRQSLLFSATVPKEVRRVSQLVLKREHGYVDTVGLGLETNPKVKQFYLVAPHEQHFQLVHHLLTSHISEVPDYKVIVFCTTAMMTSLMFSLLREMKMNVREIHSRKPQLYRTRISDEFKETKRVILITSDVSARGMNYPDVTLVIQIGIPVDREQYIHRLGRTGREGKEGEGILLLAPWEQYFLDDIKDLPMENWPVPHLDPRAKVKIEEAIGKMDASVKEAAYHAWLGYYNSVREIGRDKTTLVELANQFSESIGLQKPPSLFRRTALKMGLKDIPGIRIRK*   MGGGPRTFPGGLNKWQWKRLHEKKARDKENRLLDQEKQLYQARIRSQIRAKLTSSGEQSDFSNEQQPNYSPVSPQDHIRGLADRFMKEGAEDLWNEDDGPVNTPQINQQSGGISESIDLRKLRDTKFNDVPRSYSFQKARNFCTNISDVFAENCRTRNPTFSDSWSRQNKFLMFGWRLVNIENRNVNNLNGFLNYRCYSVDRMNGNKLRKLDFTRNESSQSEDKLRSVGLVVKGERKAKWPRFRPKPEESXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXRSRGSVKMMSSAALGKYDMKTKKRVPLKFVEDEDDLSLHVAAIRKEVKGRSMQKIETEEDEKETILSSKRFDEYDVSPLTVKALTAAGYVQMTKVQEATLSTCLEGKDALVKARTGTGKSAAFLLPAIETVLKASRKKSAQRVPPIDVLILCPTRELASQIAAEANVLLKYHEGIGVQTLVGGTRFKEDQKRLECDPCQIIVATPGRLLDHIENKSGFSTRIMGLKMLILDEADHLLDLGFRKDIEKLVDCLPRRRQSLLFSATVPKEVRRISQLVLKREYDYVDTVGLGLETNPKVKQFYLVAPHEQHFQVVHHLLSSHISEVPDYKVIVFCTTAMMTSLMFSLFHEMKMNVREIHSRKPQLYRTRISDEFKETKRVILITSDVSARGMNYPDVTLVIQVGLPVDREQYIHRLGRTGREGKEGEGILLLAPWEQYFLDDIKDLPMENWPVPRLDPRVKVKMEEAMEKMDTSVKESAYHAWLGYYNSVREVGRDKTTLVELANQFSESIGLDKPPSLFRRTALKMGLKDIPGIRIRK*  775.4   2001    414 94.0    389 25  402 0   0   97.1    0   11NRSK36SG20SCND25LI32KR16VI8HYGD29LV5TS27LFRH53IV1IL49HR4AV3IM3IMGE3AT4AS14IV20QD26    94.0    1.8e-223    94.7
gene.92134.0.0.p1   NisylASAF01033898g0006.1    NisylASAF01033898g0006.1    2.6e-302    1037.7  2682    571 548 2   570 4   548 SRDLRVAQLPLIFIGKLRQTGGESKLPSFTTVPMAFSRRXXXXXSRRRWLIPAISAAFGFLLIFIFFLSILAPSPNGNRLFHPRRRSLGDNDADTDEIEDSQSHVPARSGGVSDRDIWSSRNSKFFYGCSNASNEFLKAQDITHPNRYLSIVTSGGLNQQRTGITDAVVAARILNATLVVPKLDKSSYWKDSSGFSDIFDVDWFIKYLAKDVSIVKELPLRRGQIWSPYRMRVPRKCTDRCYINRVLPVLNKKHAVQITKFDYRLANKLDTDLQKLRCRVNYHALKFADPILGMGEKLVQRMRMRSSRFIALHLRFEPDMLAFSGCYYGGGDKERRELGKIRKKWKTLHDSDPDKARRHGRCPLTPEEVGLMLRSLGYGEDVHIYVASGEIYGGEETLTLLKALFPNFHTKDTLATKDELEPFSAFSSRMAALDFIVCDESDVFVTNNHGNMAKILAGRRRFFGHKPTIRPNGRKLYRLFLNRNYMTEKEFVYRVGKYQRGFMGEPKEVGPSWGVFHENPSSCICEKVDNATGQISHSTSRLETLSKVTSNDYDIDISENQELDMLLSD   SRDLRVAQLPLIFIGKLRQTGGESKLPSFTTVPMAFSRRXXXXXSRRRWLIPAISAAFGFLLIFIFFLSILAPSPNGNRLFHLPRRRSSGDNDADNEIEDSQSHVPAGSGGVSDRDIWSSRNSKFFYGCSNASNEFLKAQDITHPNRYLSIVTSGGLNQQRTGITDAVVAARILNATLVVPKLDKSSYWKDSSGFSDIFDVDWFIKYLAKDVSIVKELPLRRGQIWSPYRMRVPRKCTDRCYINRVLPVLNKKHAVQITKFDYRLANKLDTDLQKLRCRVNYHSLKFADPILRMGEKLVQRMRMRSSHFIALHLRFEPDMLAFSGCYYGGGDKERRELGKIRKKWKTLHDSDPDKARRHGRCPLTPEEVGLMLRSLGYGEDVHIYVASGEIYGGEETLTPLKALFPNFHTKDTLATKDELEPFSAFSSRMAALDFIVCDESDPTIRPNGRKLYRLFLNRNYMTEKEFVYRVGKYQRGFMGEPKEVGPSWGVFHENPSSCICEKVDNATVEISHSTSRLETSPKVTSNDYDTDISENPELDMLLSD   QSRDLRVAQLPLIFIGKLRQTGGESKLPSFTTVPMAFSRRXXXXXSRRRWLIPAISAAFGFLLIFIFFLSILAPSPNGNRLFHPRRRSLGDNDADTDEIEDSQSHVPARSGGVSDRDIWSSRNSKFFYGCSNASNEFLKAQDITHPNRYLSIVTSGGLNQQRTGITDAVVAARILNATLVVPKLDKSSYWKDSSGFSDIFDVDWFIKYLAKDVSIVKELPLRRGQIWSPYRMRVPRKCTDRCYINRVLPVLNKKHAVQITKFDYRLANKLDTDLQKLRCRVNYHALKFADPILGMGEKLVQRMRMRSSRFIALHLRFEPDMLAFSGCYYGGGDKERRELGKIRKKWKTLHDSDPDKARRHGRCPLTPEEVGLMLRSLGYGEDVHIYVASGEIYGGEETLTLLKALFPNFHTKDTLATKDELEPFSAFSSRMAALDFIVCDESDVFVTNNHGNMAKILAGRRRFFGHKPTIRPNGRKLYRLFLNRNYMTEKEFVYRVGKYQRGFMGEPKEVGPSWGVFHENPSSCICEKVDNATGQISHSTSRLETLSKVTSNDYDIDISENQELDMLLSD* MTLSRDLRVAQLPLIFIGKLRQTGGESKLPSFTTVPMAFSRRXXXXXSRRRWLIPAISAAFGFLLIFIFFLSILAPSPNGNRLFHLPRRRSSGDNDADNEIEDSQSHVPAGSGGVSDRDIWSSRNSKFFYGCSNASNEFLKAQDITHPNRYLSIVTSGGLNQQRTGITDAVVAARILNATLVVPKLDKSSYWKDSSGFSDIFDVDWFIKYLAKDVSIVKELPLRRGQIWSPYRMRVPRKCTDRCYINRVLPVLNKKHAVQITKFDYRLANKLDTDLQKLRCRVNYHSLKFADPILRMGEKLVQRMRMRSSHFIALHLRFEPDMLAFSGCYYGGGDKERRELGKIRKKWKTLHDSDPDKARRHGRCPLTPEEVGLMLRSLGYGEDVHIYVASGEIYGGEETLTPLKALFPNFHTKDTLATKDELEPFSAFSSRMAALDFIVCDESDPTIRPNGRKLYRLFLNRNYMTEKEFVYRVGKYQRGFMGEPKEVGPSWGVFHENPSSCICEKVDNATVEISHSTSRLETSPKVTSNDYDTDISENPELDMLLSD    1037.7  2682    570 93.2    531 13  533 3   26  93.5    0   82-L5LS6TND-11RG175AS8GR14RH91LP42V-F-V-T-N-N-H-G-N-M-A-K-I-L-A-G-R-R-R-F-F-G-H-K-66GVQE10LSSP8IT5QP8   93.2    2.6e-302    99.6
gene.71087.0.0.p1   transcript:OIT01688 transcript:OIT01688 3.8e-101    367.9   943 190 639 1   189 451 639 DRGISHAELNWPTRLKIIQGVASGMSFLHSEFASYVVPHGNLKSSNILLTEKYEPLLSDYAFYPLINNTQTVQCLFAYKSPEALQNQQISPRSDVYCLGIIILEILTGKFPSQYLNNQKGGTDIVQWVQSAIVDNRESELIDQEIANATDSSEQMVKLLHVGAACTVSDPDERIDMKEASRRIEEISLI   DRGISHAELNWPTRLKIIQGVASGMSFLHSEFASYVVPHGNLKSSNILLTEKYEPLLSDYAFYPLINNTQTVQCLFAYKSPEAIQNEQISPKSDVYCLGIIILEILTGKFPSQYLNNQKGGTDVVQWVQSAIAENRESELIDQEIANATDSIEQMVKLLHVGAACTVSDPDKRIDMKEASRRIEEISLI   DRGISHAELNWPTRLKIIQGVASGMSFLHSEFASYVVPHGNLKSSNILLTEKYEPLLSDYAFYPLINNTQTVQCLFAYKSPEALQNQQISPRSDVYCLGIIILEILTGKFPSQYLNNQKGGTDIVQWVQSAIVDNRESELIDQEIANATDSSEQMVKLLHVGAACTVSDPDERIDMKEASRRIEEISLI*  MSSNKHGRCSPLPSSSSNLSQKLLFFYISIFFLIFLSNTPFSFSISEDEALIKFKESLKNTTALDSTWHKGSNPCDKNKKWTRVQCEGNAVEGLLLGEAGLSGEIDVDPLIALPGLRVLELANNSFSGTIPEFFLLGALKSIYIDGXXXXXXXPKDFFSKMXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXESLANLKYLMELHLESXXXXXXXXSFSQASLASIDLSNNKLQGEIPQSMSKFGSDSFKGNNELCGKQLGKECNKEKENNTFQKAPMSKLKWIILGLVVGLLLITILFKAKRKEDHFDKLGKENLDEGLHVSSSNRKSMSIRSEGGDSVHGSSRRGAGSQRGKAMGDLVLVNEEKGTFGLPDLMKAAAEVLGNGVLGSAYKAKMVNGLSVVVKRLREMNKMNRDVFDTEIRKISKLRHRNILQLLAYHYRKEEKLLVSEYVPKGSLLYLLHGDRGISHAELNWPTRLKIIQGVASGMSFLHSEFASYVVPHGNLKSSNILLTEKYEPLLSDYAFYPLINNTQTVQCLFAYKSPEAIQNEQISPKSDVYCLGIIILEILTGKFPSQYLNNQKGGTDVVQWVQSAIAENRESELIDQEIANATDSIEQMVKLLHVGAACTVSDPDKRIDMKEASRRIEEISLI 367.9   943 189 95.8    181 8   187 0   0   98.9    0   83LI2QE4RK31IV8VADE17SI19EK17   95.8    3.8e-101    99.5
gene.69001.1.1.p1   NisylKD955766g0010.1    NisylKD955766g0010.1    1.4e-294    1011.9  2615    531 530 1   530 1   530 MKEMCLAVAPLPFRLGNNLIFHNPLSIGSSSHMDVTRLNSMGGTTTSLYAESAEKDLSDTVSSSRSEGVPLLHMISENESNNWISGDAVVRESEDDEILSLDGDQMSCSLSVVSDSSSLCGDDFIGFEVASEIFGQNFVDAEKSICSVELIAKPGDLVESGVEDDNVSKPFAVKIEEQITDGSSSKSSQVVVQLPLNKGLSAAVSRSVFEVDYIPLWGFTSVCGRRPEMEDALATVPRFLRIPLQMLVGHRVPDGVSRCLSHLTAHFFGVYDGHGGSQVANYCRDRVHAVLAEELEKFMANLNDESIRQNCQEQWKKAFTNCFLMVDDEVGGTGNHEAVAAETVGSTAVVAIVCSSHIIVANCGDSRAVLCRGKEPTALSVDHKPNREDEYARIEAAGGKVIQWNGHRVFGVLAMSRSIGDRYLKPWIIPDPEVMFIPRTKDDECLILASDGLWDVMSNEEACELARKRILLWHKKNGVTLTLERGQGIDPAAQAAAECLSNRAIQKGSKDNITVIVVDLKAQRKFKSKT  MKEMCLAVAPLPFRLGNNLIFRNPPSIGSSSHMDATRLNSMGDTTTSLYAESAEKDLSDTVSSSRSEGVPLLPMISENDRNNWIAGDAVVRESEDDEILSLDGDQVSCSLSVVSDSSSLCGDDFIGFEVASDIYGQNFVDAEKSICSVELIAKPGDLVESGVEDDNVSKPFAVKLEEQITDGSSSKSSQVVVQLPLNKGLSAAVSRSVFEVDYIPLWGFTSVCGRRPEMEDALATVPRFLRIPLQMLVGDRVPDGVSRCLSHLTAHFFGVYDGHGGSQVANYCRDRVHAVLAEELEKFMANLNDESIRQNCQDQWKKAFTNCFLKVDDEVGGTGNREAVAAETVGSTAVVAIVCSSHIIVANCGDSRAVLCRGKEPMALSVDHKPNREDEYARIEAAGGKVIQWNGHRVFGVLAMSRSIGDRYLKPWIIPDPEVMFIPRTKDDECLILASDGLWDVMSNEEACELARKRILLWHKKNGVTLTLERGQGIDPAAQAAAECLSNRATQKGSKDNITVIVVDLKAQRKFKSKT  MKEMCLAVAPLPFRLGNNLIFHNPLSIGSSSHMDVTRLNSMGGTTTSLYAESAEKDLSDTVSSSRSEGVPLLHMISENESNNWISGDAVVRESEDDEILSLDGDQMSCSLSVVSDSSSLCGDDFIGFEVASEIFGQNFVDAEKSICSVELIAKPGDLVESGVEDDNVSKPFAVKIEEQITDGSSSKSSQVVVQLPLNKGLSAAVSRSVFEVDYIPLWGFTSVCGRRPEMEDALATVPRFLRIPLQMLVGHRVPDGVSRCLSHLTAHFFGVYDGHGGSQVANYCRDRVHAVLAEELEKFMANLNDESIRQNCQEQWKKAFTNCFLMVDDEVGGTGNHEAVAAETVGSTAVVAIVCSSHIIVANCGDSRAVLCRGKEPTALSVDHKPNREDEYARIEAAGGKVIQWNGHRVFGVLAMSRSIGDRYLKPWIIPDPEVMFIPRTKDDECLILASDGLWDVMSNEEACELARKRILLWHKKNGVTLTLERGQGIDPAAQAAAECLSNRAIQKGSKDNITVIVVDLKAQRKFKSKT* MKEMCLAVAPLPFRLGNNLIFRNPPSIGSSSHMDATRLNSMGDTTTSLYAESAEKDLSDTVSSSRSEGVPLLPMISENDRNNWIAGDAVVRESEDDEILSLDGDQVSCSLSVVSDSSSLCGDDFIGFEVASDIYGQNFVDAEKSICSVELIAKPGDLVESGVEDDNVSKPFAVKLEEQITDGSSSKSSQVVVQLPLNKGLSAAVSRSVFEVDYIPLWGFTSVCGRRPEMEDALATVPRFLRIPLQMLVGDRVPDGVSRCLSHLTAHFFGVYDGHGGSQVANYCRDRVHAVLAEELEKFMANLNDESIRQNCQDQWKKAFTNCFLKVDDEVGGTGNREAVAAETVGSTAVVAIVCSSHIIVANCGDSRAVLCRGKEPMALSVDHKPNREDEYARIEAAGGKVIQWNGHRVFGVLAMSRSIGDRYLKPWIIPDPEVMFIPRTKDDECLILASDGLWDVMSNEEACELARKRILLWHKKNGVTLTLERGQGIDPAAQAAAECLSNRATQKGSKDNITVIVVDLKAQRKFKSKT  1011.9  2615    530 96.6    512 18  519 0   0   97.9    0   21HR2LP9VA7GD29HP5EDSR4SA20MV25ED1FY40IL74HD62ED11MK10HR40TM127IT25 96.6    1.4e-294    99.8
gene.96656.0.5.p2   NisylKD954897g0030.1    NisylKD954897g0030.1    7.7e-75 280.0   715 140 968 1   139 371 509 MRCKYLTLNTPMKKWELHGIAILLQSCPWVEMLHINTESAFEVYHFGLHYKNSNDFNGENYWISRPCWVLHLKTLRIHGYEWWDGDEYMLSFLQVVLKNGMVLQKIIIDFFEINSYEKLTKKLLSFPRSSREAVILFSS MRCKYLTLNTPMKKWELPGIAILLQSCPQVEMLHINTESAFEEYHFGSHFKNSNDFNGENYWISRPCWVLHLKTLRIHGYEWWDGDEYILSFLQVVLKNGMVLQKIIIDFFEINSYEKLTKKLLSFPRSSREAVILFSN MRCKYLTLNTPMKKWELHGIAILLQSCPWVEMLHINTESAFEVYHFGLHYKNSNDFNGENYWISRPCWVLHLKTLRIHGYEWWDGDEYMLSFLQVVLKNGMVLQKIIIDFFEINSYEKLTKKLLSFPRSSREAVILFSS*    MSESEGEHEENLDYDSPRYSPYSXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXSDQSYYGGKCHKTEKTDRISALPDSLILHILSSLDMGEVVRTGVLSKRWHLLWTSQQSLIFSYSGQHVNGIYKFVIFIDNTLLLCRSGMVKKFSVDFIYSKRFVRHVNRWMIFIKNKLVEELDLNLRSRGNLIEIYNLPQIMYFDVRLRHLSLCNCNLVPKEEIYWPALRDLEIGYAELNRDVIKKICSGCRALESLKFRSCYGVDYFDIDSKSVKKLVIHEYGRQNHDDADDDDDELGIYARNVTSLEICGYFHKRILVLEDVKALLDAKLDFYRNTDDYEIEREFRTDQNMLKNLLVSLQHVEKLSIGTWCLQVLTSLEIRNLPCPRMRCKYLTLNTPMKKWELPGIAILLQSCPQVEMLHINTESAFEEYHFGSHFKNSNDFNGENYWISRPCWVLHLKTLRIHGYEWWDGDEYILSFLQVVLKNGMVLQKIIIDFFEINSYEKLTKKLLSFPRSSREAVILFSNRFSSLPDSVLLHILSFLPFDDVVRTTLLCKQWRPLWSFSTSLNFIHRPKDFISLKKFASFVDKSLINLHCNNSSISKLHLDFPFKRCFSSDVTVWVLFAITHKVKELNLILSSDAEDLYKLPKRLFSNPFIEKVNWVGCKFDKVEVFRWDSLRELRIGSIEFCDDMVRKVVFGSPCLELLELDNCWGFKRLDLVGGKVSKLVVNGYNGEAVKKNSMLLDFEVVEIEAPCVKVLELKGCFRRMNNIQLKNVMSCVSVKLDFQFTKDEERVNYVDMLMGMIGSLRHVKDVMLGTWCIEVMSSWPMNILPFSMSSYECLTLHTPIQERYLPGIVRILQSSSNLRTLIIHMAPPYFEFEACFIPIVYDVYSVGGRCQLSMLSKNCGLHLKKIRICCFEGMRSGQEVLFLRDLLLVCANLEEMVIEWRSGHQNSSIRDASDEFVAESLLMVQKRSRNAVILFNN    280.0   715 139 95.0    132 7   135 0   0   97.1    0   17HP10WQ13VE4LS1YF38MI49SN  95.0    7.7e-75 99.3
gene.86248.0.0.p1   Nitab4.5_0000420g0110.1 Nitab4.5_0000420g0110.1 Protein of unknown function DUF538  8.2e-74 276.9   707 175 140 35  174 1   140 MTSQVTENHRENAEVFTNPAICKQKSLELLEQTNMPKGLLPLDDLIEVGRNHQTGFVWLKQKKAKEHRFKKIGKLVWYDTEVTAFVEDRRMKKLTGVKSKEILIWVTISDISIQDPEFQKITFATPTGISKAFPVSAFEE    MSSQVSENHRENAEVFTDPAICKQKSLELLEQINMPKGLLPLDDLIEVGRNHQTGFVWLKQKKAKEHRFKKIGKLVWYDTEVTAFIEDRRMKKLTGVKSKEILIWVTISDISIQDPEFQKITFATPTGISKAFPVSAFEE    THFLYFPFPLSHTEPQTKRNLNPISFPFSFAFTKMTSQVTENHRENAEVFTNPAICKQKSLELLEQTNMPKGLLPLDDLIEVGRNHQTGFVWLKQKKAKEHRFKKIGKLVWYDTEVTAFVEDRRMKKLTGVKSKEILIWVTISDISIQDPEFQKITFATPTGISKAFPVSAFEE* MSSQVSENHRENAEVFTDPAICKQKSLELLEQINMPKGLLPLDDLIEVGRNHQTGFVWLKQKKAKEHRFKKIGKLVWYDTEVTAFIEDRRMKKLTGVKSKEILIWVTISDISIQDPEFQKITFATPTGISKAFPVSAFEE    276.9   707 140 96.4    135 5   139 0   0   99.3    0   1TS3TS11ND14TI52VI54    96.4    8.2e-74 80.0
```

Comment: Yes, the problem is after the latest change, I'll need to edit, because if you look now, anytime the prefix and the 30th field are equal, that line is being stored, not just when it is the lowest. the `else if` needs another change after you added the last criteria. I'll update in a bit.

Answer (score 1):

Could you please try following, written and tested with shown samples only. Also as per OP's comments ignoring lines which are NOT starting from `gene`.

```
awk '
/^chr/ { print; next }
match($0,/^gene\.[0-9]+/){
  val=substr($0,RSTART,RLENGTH)
  arr[val]=(arr[val]>$30?$30:arr[val])
  valArr[val]=$0
}
END{
  for(i in arr){
    print valArr[i]
  }
}
' Input_file
```

---

---

***EDIT:*** As per OP's comment in case minimum value has multiple lines then try following.

```
awk '
/^chr/ { print; next }
match($0,/^gene\.[0-9]+/){
  val=substr($0,RSTART,RLENGTH)
  arr[val]=(arr[val]>$30?$30:arr[val])
  valArr[val]=(valArr[val]?valArr[val] ORS:"")$0
}
END{
  for(i in arr){
    print valArr[i]
  }
}
' Input_file
```

Comment: @user977828, see this difference `echo "abcd12234" | awk '{print $0+0}'` is `0` AND `echo "1234abcd12234" | awk '{print $0+0}'` is `1234` so if your 30th field starts from digits and you want to have initial digits then go ahead, else use `sub` function to remove all non numeric things and get only digits in that field.